# Embedding an onClick() function on an HTML element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['player_info'], (data) => {
    console.log('search')
    console.log(data)
    // data = list of possible players 
    let player_arr = data.player_info
    for (let i = 0; i < player_arr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("card-wrapper").innerHTML +=
            `<div onclick="alert('clicked')" class="player_option">
                <center>
                    <div class="card-img-small">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img id=\"player_img\" src="${player_arr[i].profile_img}" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="player-name" class="price-small">
                        ${player_arr[i].name}
                    </div>`
    }
})
```

I am dynamically rendering some items using the code above. 
In the `div` wrapper, I added an `alert` function to check if it works, but nothing happens. I inspected the element, and it looked like this:

```
<div onclick="alert('clicked')" class="player_option">
                <center>
                    <div class="card-img-small">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img id="player_img" src="https://fmdataba.com/images/p/4348.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="player-name" class="price-small">
                        Paul Pogba
                    </div></div></div>
```

It seems like the function is embedded correctly, but the `alert` doesn't happen. Any help?

**EDIT**

Actually realized I am getting this error: `Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.` I am building a Chrome Extension

Comment: can you try with console.log('132') instead of alert()? and check

Comment: Same. It doesn't work

Comment: can you share it in fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

In chrome apps and extentions, Content Security Policy does not allow inline javascript. So you have to put your javascript in a .js file and include it in your HTML.

You have to use js event listener instead. Take a look at this:
[Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates CSP. (SANDBOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox)

If you still want to use js in `onClick` attributes, you could also change the `Content Security Policy`. Look at: [Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy) under "Relaxing the default policy".