# How to find source for "Refused to execute inline event handler Because violates CSP blabla"

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

**Keep getting this error and i know what it means, But can't find the source.**

[image]

**click the console source only leads me here.**

[image]

Comment: May this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox) help you?

Comment: sadly, not, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [`report-uri`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri) to your CSP header, then look at the generated report. It will tell you the source file and the line number.

The generated report will go to your URI, but it will also be visible in the network tab in the browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Just search your source code (html) for any inline instances of `on*="..."` (e.g. onClick, onclick, onSubmit, etc..) since you seem to have inline event handlers.

Other event handler names can be found here and in the linked documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers

Comment: that's what i thought, I'm looking for a traceable solution.