# I keep getting the error "Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Chrome extension that needs JavaScript. How can I include JavaScript in my Chrome extension?

This is the popup.Json as it has requested me to do.

```js
function AddNewPopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

And here is the script tool that it keeps blocking.
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="AddNewPopup()"><button class="addnew"><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Test for 0.9</span><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSH-bdYc7hZzKrjl7v1tMC2qEwo7F_3HgFWyQ&usqp=CAU" width="50"></button></div>
```

Please tell me how to get rid of this security issue and insert my JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an `onclick` handler in your html like that (an example of inline javascript) is not allowed in extensions.

To get it to work you'll need to include `popup.js` from your html and from within `popup.js` register the onclick hander like so:

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

popup.js:

```
document.getElementById('myPopup').addEventListener("click", AddNewPopup);
```

You can read more about that error in this article here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work. Do i put the script around the button i had? It's not working.

Comment: Add `<script src="popup.js"></script>` above the `<div>...</div>` line you have. Then in popup.js register the click listener. You'll need to remove the `onclick="AddNewPopup()"` that you have. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox

Comment: Um, it still didn't work.
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<div class="popup"><button class="addnew"><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Test for 0.9</span><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSH-bdYc7hZzKrjl7v1tMC2qEwo7F_3HgFWyQ&usqp=CAU" width="50"></button></div>

Comment: Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.  ```<script src="popup.js"></script> ```

Comment: It stopped the moment it saw "script". I really need to add this or else my extension will not function.

Comment: That's weird - the chrome link I posted in my original answer details this very use case.

Comment: Yeah, I consulted the website and it didn't work either.

Comment: @CruzeHeadphones Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm facing the same in my angular app.