# Chrome extension with Angular: CSP inline-policy error. Refused to execute inline event handler

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I would like to associate a logout function to the navbar of a chrome extension.
But when I click on the respective tab, it doesn't navigate to the signin component and gives me the following error:

**Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.**

At https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/contentSecurityPolicy/ it says that we can't use inline scripting in your Chrome App pages and the restriction bans both  blocks and event handlers ().

I've seen solutions on stackoverflow such as this [Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates CSP. (SANDBOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox) that say that we could add an id to the button and then add an eventlistener on the javascript but this way I could not add this line of code: this.router.navigate(['/signin']) as is.

I think I could have a typescript file transpiled to javascript but if I place document.getElementById(<id_of_button>) on the ts file it retrieves me null, I think the typescript is loaded before the template.

How can I solve this chrome extension error with Angular and Typescript?

I've the code as below:

**App.component.html**

```
    <mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menuAccount"><mat-icon fontSet="fas" style="font-size: 18px;" fontIcon="fa-user-circle"></mat-icon></button>
      </ng-template>
      <mat-menu #menuAccount="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item><mat-icon fontSet="fa" style="font-size: 16px;" fontIcon="fa-cogs"></mat-icon><span>{{dpd_items[0].viewValue}}</span></button>
        <button (click)="logout()" mat-menu-item><mat-icon fontSet="fas" style="font-size: 16px;" fontIcon="fa-sign-out-alt"></mat-icon><span>{{dpd_items[1].viewValue}}</span></button>
      </mat-menu>
    </mat-tab>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
logout() {
  this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this error came from the CSS being extracted to InlineJs not from the angular code itself.

This meant for me that it works with a build watch,

```
"angular:watch": "ng build --watch",
```

but not a build production.

```
"angular:build": "ng build --configuration=production",
```

The solution here was to disable the extractCSS.

You can adjust the angular.json in production to extractCss: false

```
{
    ...
    "projects": {
        "project-name": {
            ...
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    ...
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            ...
                            "extractCss": false,
                            ...
```