# Angular gives `Refused to execute inline event handler` error

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

I have created an angular application.  which gives the following error in the browser

[image]

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

The reason is that angular injects the following in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
```

Its that `onload="this.media='all'"`

One solution is to set `"optimization"` to false, in which case angular doesn't inject this code. But that doesn't sound like the best solution. Any suggestions how to do this?

An other solution, which I think is a little bit better than the previous one, is to create a wrapper component  which holds all the styling from `styles.scss`. In my case, for this to work, I also needed to to set the `encapsultaion` of that wrapper component to `ViewEncapsulation.None`

Comment: Does it happen after you click something? Or just loading it?

Comment: it happens on initial load

Comment: Any chance it gives you which file it is? Sounds like it's trying to protect the code because there's some potentially usnafe execution.

Comment: I found the code which is the root cause of this issue. In my `styles.scss` I have a couple of scss and css imports (they import thrid party styles). When I remove them the error disappears. I think `styles.scss` is compiled into css and injected into `index.html`. I think this is the reason. Can this be solved?

Comment: Could you maybe host the third party css's yourself? Is there anything odd in them?

Comment: I found the problem, I've updated the post. Angular injects an inline script for loading that styles.css file

Comment: "Angular injects an inline script" was exactly my problem too. Thank you @JeanlucaScaljeri

Comment: As an immediate fix we're using `optimization` for now, but agree with your assessment that the second solution seems preferable. In the future hope to try out that second solution - `ViewEncapsulation.None` indeed seems to be the critical bit. Thank you for sharing your discoveries

Answer (score 21):

I had to add this on production configuration on angular.json

```
"optimization": {
  "scripts": true,
  "styles": {
    "minify": true,
    "inlineCritical": false
  },
  "fonts": true
},
```

Because `"optimization": false` makes the bundle size too big.

Comment: Yes, this right here! It seems to have fixed our issue completely. Are there any downsides to this solution though?

Comment: Also, looks like Angular is supposed to be addressing CSP issues at some point in the future per a comment at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26152#issuecomment-886820961

Answer (score 0):

The root cause and fix is covered here: [Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates CSP. (SANDBOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox) Getting Angular to do it in a better way might be a challenge.

As the error message says, you can allow it with 'unsafe-hashes', but that is a feature of CSP level 3 and only implemented in Chromium browsers.