# CSP style-src SHA256 present, but browser issues warning that it isn't

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I've added the following CSP to my nginx configuration:

> add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'none'; script-src
> 'self'; img-src *.gravatar.com; script-src-elem 'self'
> 'sha256-HeezHnLPgcw5524/5YMbWWQXJ/fdKZsQX5vG7t1UmJw='
> 'sha256-FVzC2JpGNv45prICvPCadmKf+wnLz6Eem3UQaAnTK/4='
> 'sha256-Tr3bLHN4KJG2A/qFIDTX+Yb0nG+Z+HS9VAD6k0/r+vY='
> 'sha256-NYk7Q8DQLjjJRwkQ9oG2juhRXSdsOjLWMy0IpXWymRc='
> 'sha256-pu6oe0vPSMzzITPF3U0Z8qBWhbBKykixk7D9kFsDySY='; script-src-attr
> 'self'; style-src
> 'sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='; style-src-elem
> 'self' 'sha256-OyKg6OHgnmapAcgq002yGA58wB21FOR7EcTwPWSs54E='
> 'sha256-CK/6NyEbsJb3V2Bo26t3s0V3RAi3gTWWrjUNGLIZLfw='
> 'sha256-hc4UHa0RDFRaKgh++CLvhy5nf4yco/u+xPDeTrTejhg=';";

My browser (Chrome) issues the following warning:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'
> 'sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes
> do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript:
> navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

As you can see the hash `style-src 'sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='` is present and set, but the browser is saying there's a still a problem.

I can't work this out. Any help?

Comment: Any example of the forbidden use? Check twice the advice "Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered well here: [Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates CSP. (SANDBOX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324333/refused-to-execute-inline-event-handler-because-it-violates-csp-sandbox)

As user27878850 suggests, you could add 'unsafe-hashes', but that would currently only work in Chromium browsers.