# only showing image name when I upload it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to upload an image from a file browser dialog .I want the image to be previewed  as the user selects the image.It is working in jsfiddle but it isn't working in my project .

The error is

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

I don't know how to solve it. Please help me?

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('previewImg').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
}

document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.thumb {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='file' id="files" name="image" multiple="multiple" />
<div id='previewImg'></div>
```

Comment: Can you post your fiddle link too? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null)

Comment: Search this `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"` in google.. you probably find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your `document.getElementById ('files')` command is running before the page is fully renderd, so the selector can not find any element on the page, and you cant add `addEventListener` to no elements.

You have to put the selector inside document loaded function, like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}, false);
```