# jQuery select pre-exising button in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I want to make an extension that changes the title on Chrome's built in stopwatch when i start and stop it. I am getting an error trying to retrieve the button's class. The JavaScript works when pasted in the browser console so I think the problem is with the json file.

Here is my JavaScript.

```
   var title = document.querySelector("title");

    var button = document.querySelector(".act-desktop-button");

    var flip = true;

    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    flip =! flip;
    console.log(flip);

    if(flip === true){
    title.textContent = "OFF";
    } else{
    title.textContent = "ON";
    }
    });
```

and here is my json

```
    {  
    "name": "Stopwatch Tracker",

    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "works with chromes built in stopwatch feature. Changes the 
    title of the page to 'ON' or 'OFF' depending on if the stopwatch is 
    running.",

    "permissions":[
    "tabs",
    "*://*.google.com/search?q=stopwatch*"
    ],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["*://*.google.com/search?q=stopwatch*"],
    "js": ["background.js"]
    }
    ],

    "manifest_version": 2

    }
```

I am receiving this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what is the most important part here is to make sure that you have checked the value of `button` to be not `null` before adding an event listener.

Just like this:

```
var button = document.querySelector(".act-desktop-button");

    var flip = true;
if (button){
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
...
})};
```

Try also to check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null) as this is related to your question.