# ElementById finds element but won't add event listener (Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a form in my extension's popup with the code:

```
<button type="submit" id="update" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

And then in the attached script, the following code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
  var button = document.getElementById("update");
  button.addEventListener("click", test);
  button.style.color="red";
});



function test(){
  console.log("test");
}
```

The "button.style.color="red"" portion of the code works, so I know that the button was found successfully. However, I still receive this error upon load and when the button is clicked:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

How do I fix this :(

Comment: I assume the problem is that your button is not in the DOM before your popup shows.

Answer (score 0):

It is working in my demos, see: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hepiruropu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event){
     var button = document.getElementById("update");
     button.addEventListener("click", test);
     button.style.color="red"; 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a possible duplicate [Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null/30063375) but, try these solutions out, if your still having trouble explain more in detail.