# [JS, html]Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I have problem.
When I want to run sound from image I got error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

My html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Music</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" src="http://www.soundboard.com/handler/DownLoadTrack.ashx?cliptitle=Never+Gonna+Give+You+Up-+Original&filename=mz/Mzg1ODMxNTIzMzg1ODM3_JzthsfvUY24.MP3"></audio>

    <script>
    document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
    });
    </script>

    <a href="#" id="play">
        <img src="test.png">
    </a>
</body>
<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Your JS code is above the element.  The DOM has not loaded the element yet, so it is undefined.  Either move your script below the element, or add it to an onload event handler so it runs *after* the DOM has fully loaded.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna remember next time :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run your script after the document is fully loaded so that the tag with id : 'play' actually exists.

Something like this

```
window.onload=function(){
  ...
}
```

**P.S : **  Source for solution and alternate potential fixes : [Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null)