# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, Is there a better way to prevent this

Tags: javascript

If we have two elements in two different pages say 'element1' in page-1 and 'element2' in page-2.
And we have a single javascript linking both the pages say 'main.js' like this

**HTML (PAGE 1)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="elementOne">THIS IS ELEMENT ONE</h1>
   <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTML (PAGE 2)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h1 class="elementTwo">THIS IS ELEMENT TWO</h1>
   <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**MAIN.JS (JAVASCRIPT FILE LINKING BOTH PAGES)**

```
let elementOne = document.querySelector(".elementOne");
let elementTwo = document.querySelector(".elementTwo");


elementOne.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    console.log("element1");
})

elementTwo.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    console.log("element2");
})
```

If the current page is 'page1' we get a error

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Because
`document.querySelector(".elementTwo);`
returns `null`,

Since element with the class 'elementTwo'
does not exist in PAGE1

I found a solution for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107125/cannot-read-property-addeventlistener-of-null)

In the link provided above, they are checking for `null` like this

```
if(elementOne){
    elementOne.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        console.log("element1");
    })
}

if(elementTwo){
    elementTwo.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        console.log("element2");
    })
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?.
I also observed that this problem does not occur if we use jQuery.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Could you put the shared function(s) in another file? Then each page would contain a stub which injects its `"element1"` or `"element2"` as function arguments. [There are different ways to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file), some made easier by JS packaging tools.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining): notice the question mark behind elementOne and elementTwo

```js
let elementOne = document.querySelector(".elementOne");
let elementTwo = document.querySelector(".elementTwo");


elementOne?.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("element1");
})

elementTwo?.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  console.log("element2");
})
```

```html
<h1 class="elementOne">THIS IS ELEMENT ONE</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

With [the relatively new optional chaining](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining):

```js
elementOne?.addEventListener("click", ...)
```

Or, for compatibility with older browsers, the less readable method with boolean short-circuiting (you should probably just use an if statement instead of this):

```js
elementOne && elementOne.addEventListener("click", ...)
```