# How to prevent an eventListner for the first time on pageLoad In JS

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

**i have used preventDefault() but thats not working**
here is My Code

```
btnBookNameSearch.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const searchValue = btnBookNameSearch.value.toLowerCase().trim();
 
    allPgBooks.forEach((product) => {
        if (product.name == searchValue) {
            allPgBooksE2.innerHTML = '';
            if (allPgBooksE2) {
```

**there is a mistake i am doing in the first two line of code above but idk how to fix ....the Error i am getting is ....Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') ...**

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34281265/16688813)

Comment: Chances are your loading the script in your HTML head, a common method of loading scripts these days is to place before the body closing tag.. `....<script src="xyz"/></body>`...

Answer (score 1):

Your btnBookNamsSearch is null. Probably you trying to find the button by wrong id or selector.

Comment: const btnBookNameSearch = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
 
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSearch" Class="btn btn-primary custom" runat="server"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></asp:LinkButton>

Answer (score 0):

It just means that the variable `btnBookNameSearch` is empty. It couldn't find the element that supposed to be inside that variable. It could be typo in the way you retrieved the element, e.g. `document.querySelector('.element-class')`.

Answer (score 0):

use DOMContentLoaded event. Add your code inside the callback function

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // Your code to run, DOM is loaded and ready
   btnBookNameSearch.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   const searchValue = btnBookNameSearch.value.toLowerCase().trim();
   .....
   .....
});
```