# TypeError: document.body is null

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Why I getting error in browser?

> TypeError: document.body is null

Code is working well in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8b8u5bp).

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jsscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var creElem = document.createElement("p");
creElem.innerHTML = "Hellow World";
creElem.setAttribute("id", "id_name");
document.body.appendChild(creElem);
```

Comment: JSFiddle run your script after the page loaded. ("onLoad" in left panel)

Comment: @MichaelPerlakowski is it possible to observe an `{}` for changes with `MutationObserver`??

Answer (score 18):

Execute the code when the DOM loads. Wrap your logic in an event listener for `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // ...
});
```

The reason it worked in JSFiddle is because the JS is executed on load (that's the default option in JSFiddle).

---

Alternatively, depending on when you need the logic to be executed, you could also use:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // ...
});
```

See: [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and Load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)

Comment: is it possible to observe an `{}` for changes with `MutationObserver`??

Answer (score 4):

Your `document.body` is not created or not existing yet. If you want to append child to `document.body` or do anything with `document.body` in your javascript then put your javascript code or link of js file in the end of body tag.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="jsscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```