# Getting Intermittent "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null" ERROR?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code that iterates through an array (which is fed by an object) and processes image sources to be invoked in an iframe. The issue is, I'm getting an

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

ERROR when reloading page. If I do a `Empty Cache and Hard reload` it seems to works fine 100%. If I navigate away and back it works fine 95% of the time. If I do a regular reload, the error occurs almost every time on the last line, of the initial image source (`document.body.appendChild(iframeTag);` ) in the following code.  I do however see the initial image source call going out :

```
function insertStaticTag(imgSrc) {
    var iframeTag = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeTag.setAttribute("width", "1");
    iframeTag.setAttribute("height", "1");
    iframeTag.style.display = "none";
    iframeTag.style.border = "none";
    var imgTag = document.createElement("img");
    imgTag.src = detokenizeTags(imgSrc);
    iframeTag.appendChild(imgTag);
    document.body.appendChild(iframeTag);
};
```

Not sure why this is happening or how to fix? Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833117/typeerror-document-body-is-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means `document.body` is `null`. You can avoid it by executing the code after the DOM is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     // The code
});
```

Comment: This worked: 
`if(window.addEventListener)
   window.addEventListener("load", function() {  document.body.appendChild(iframeTag); }, false);
 else
   window.attachEvent("onload", function() {  document.body.appendChild(iframeTag); });
};`