# Something blocking load event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Something weird appears on a website I developed. Page content is loaded in 5 or 6s, but the `DOMContentLoaded` and Load Event actually fires after 1m 10s.

[image]

When I reload page during loading it loads fast. Any hints welcome !

EDIT: I disabled soundcloud API call, and I'm still in troubles.
Server error logs are empty.

Here is a link to the [website.](http://belugas-trio.fr)

Comment: Check for any external script included that may take long to load

Comment: Move that api.soundcloud.com request into an AJAX call so it doesn't delay the page load event.

Comment: I use the Soundcloud Sdk to handle the request. It loads on window.load, so it should'nt cause trouble?

Comment: Please use the proper tags, this has nothing to do with CakePHP or php at all.

Answer (score 0):

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading.

After the DOM Content is loaded, images, scripts, fonts, etc still need to finish loading.

For more information on the difference between DOMContentLoaded and Load events check out:
[Difference between DOMContentLoaded and Load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)

There lots of ways of improving this events timings.

Checkout out page speed best practices:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/rules

You can even use the chrome extension tool to help you out.
https://developers.google.com/speed/