# $(this) not working as onload event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onload

Im trying to start a function when the page is loaded by a onload event which i include in the body tag. My function needs the `$(this)` value. The problem here is that the $(this) will not work in the function. But it works when I use the onClick event any ideas why and how to fix it?

This don't work.

```
<body onload="infoPopUp($(this), 3);">
```

This does.

```
<body onclick="infoPopUp($(this), 3);">
```

Comment: Please provide some code examples to provide context to your question.

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question. Any code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to access `$(document.body)` from onload?

Comment: For either one, you need to add the closing `"` double quotes...

Comment: What do you want to do with 'this' inside the function? Is $("body") won't satisfy?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily replicate the `<body onload="">` and `<body onclick="">` in jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    // your document has been loaded
    // infoPopUp($('body'), 3) can be used here
});
```

Comment: Sidenote, `load` and `domcontentloaded` (document ready) are technically different events though they should both work in theory. See this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events as a reference...

Comment: Didn't know about the `DOMContentLoaded` event.  In most cases I would want to use `Load` anyway =].  Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Body is in `document.body` + you forgot to close quotes.

```
<body onload="infoPopUp(document.body, 3);">
```

Comment: Your closing quote should be after the semicolon.

Comment: @RobertLee: you're right, but why downvote for typo which do nothing bad? In JS the semicolon is optional in this case and in html will be ignored. It works in all cases: with semicolon before ", after " and without it.