# property 'addEventListener' of null on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I have a button on my page that when I mouse over I would like to change to the background color to red. I am getting this error:

Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="dev" onclick="visibility()">Visibility</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
var ditto = document.getElementById("dev");
ditto.addEventListener("mouseover", buttonColor);

function buttonColor(){
    document.getElementById("dev").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

here's what I thought I was doing:

created a variable for the specific element i wanted. Then add an eventlistener to that element for "mouseover" that would call the function buttonColor. buttonColor would change background color of button.

what did I do wrong?

edit: my js is an external file.
I have to use the add event lisenter for a homework objective.

Comment: Add this script at the bottom of `body` element or use `DOMContentLoaded` event handler if script is in `head` element

Comment: my script is actually an external file

Comment: And my guess is that you're including it in `head` element

Comment: Yes my js file is linked in the head element

Comment: Tushar is correct, it will then try to find the element the before it exists (has been read).

Comment: @kronis72 See my first comment :)

Comment: so do i use DOMContentLoaded instead of mouseover? I tried that and didnt work? im still getting the same console error

Comment: Wrap it : `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // your script });`.

Comment: @Shikkediel  if I wrap it, it seems to be red all the time, like from the time the page loads, I want it to only turn red if the mouse is over it

Comment: That makes no sense unless it was red to begin with...

Comment: @Shikkediel no its just the standard button color, meaning i didnt set any colors for the button in any fashion..... Im still playing with trying to figure out whats going on.

Comment: @Shikkediel   mmmm my apologies, I see that I was doing something wrong based on your example below. that does infact work. thank you

Comment: Dunno about strict mode but why use it. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGNVme?editors=101

Comment: @Shikkediel i edited my prior comment, but I was making a mistake with my script that I can now see via your example. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting this part

```
var ditto = document.getElementById("dev");
ditto.addEventListener("mouseover", buttonColor);
```

And adding `onmouseover="buttonColor()"` just like you did with `visibility()` like so

```
<button type="button" id="dev" onmouseover="buttonColor()" onclick="visibility()">Visibility</button>
```

**Edit:**

Just like the others said in the comments, the issue is that your HTML is not yet loaded when the code i suggested to delete actually runs

You can move the script at the end of `<body>` so it executes after the `button` is on page

Comment: I should have stated this, but I have to use an event lisenter as this is for a homework objective

Comment: And changing external JS for inline isn't great practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="dev" onmouseover="overColor()" onmouseout="normalColor()">Visibility</button>
```

Javascript

```
function overColor(){
    document.getElementById("dev").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function normalColor(){
    document.getElementById("dev").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

**Explanation**

The **onClick** event fires when you click the button, you don't need this.

The **mouseOver** event is fired when your mouse is in the button area, which is what you need here.

The **mouseOut** event is fired when your mouse leaves the area of the button.

Comment: I edited my original question, I have to use an eventlisenter and the onclick is for a different function

Comment: You should refer to Tushar's comment. It answers your question. Please be careful to describe what you want to achieve precisely in future :)

Answer (score 0):

your code is running correctly without any error. i have re-run on fiddle here is my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tDQWN/7751/)

please provide your fiddle in which you facing an same error.so that i can help you out.

also you can add more than one eventlistner like provided in my fiddle. you can see.

here is my JS

```
var ditto = document.getElementById("dev");
ditto.addEventListener("mouseover", buttonColor);
ditto.addEventListener("mouseout", buttonColorOut);
ditto.addEventListener("click", click);

function buttonColor(){
    document.getElementById("dev").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function buttonColorOut(){
    document.getElementById("dev").style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

function click(){
    alert("clicked");
}
function visibility(){
    alert("clicked");
}
```

and HTML is

```
<button type="button" id="dev" onclick="visibility()">Visibility</button>
```

Comment: while it may work in jsfiddle it does not work when I view through my browser. W firebug I get no errors just doesnt function correctly and in chrome, I get the null error as stated above, Im confused why it would work in jsfiddle, but not local. apparently tushar's comment is how to solved the problem, but i dont understand how to use the DOMContentLoaded event handler, still trying to figure it out

Comment: sorry i don't get you exactly where you exactly getting an error in your code although i have also used chrome for checking but in my case it is working fine.

Comment: you may refer to this question for DOMcontentLoad may be it will help you to figure out your error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Comment: I think the code editors automatically place any script at the bottom of the document (instead of the head) so the issue doesn't show then.

Comment: this is the line chrome gives me the console error for................ditto.addEventListener("mouseover", buttonColor);

Comment: what I dont understand is how DOMcontentLoad or load, effects my add eventlisenter. so Im kind of stuck, Trying to figure it out, but im more confused now then when i started

Comment: Your script is read before the HTML itself so it cannot add a listener to what isn't there yet. If it is placed at the bottom, or executed after all has been loaded, it will be able to find the element.

Comment: according to my search  " The DOMContentLoaded event fires when the pages HTML and scripts have loaded, but not necessarily any images or CSS." although i dont have familier with the use of that.

Comment: @kronis72 DOMContentLoaded is and another eventlistner like you applied. but we use this one to make loading of your script after your HTML loaded. try this one    "   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function ()
    {
        // write your mouseover code here....
    }) "        may be it will help you