# Why class selector is not created on click action?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

Below is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
            ev.target.classList.toggle('done');
        }
    }, false);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Buy milk</li>
        <li>Take the dog for a walk</li>
        <li>Exercise</li>
        <li>Write code</li>
        <li>Play music</li>
        <li>Relax</li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

below is the CSS code:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 2em;
  background: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

li.done {
  background: #CCFF99;
}

li.done::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-color: #009933;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0.3em 0.25em 0;
  height: 1em;
  top: 1.3em;
  left: 0.6em;
  margin-top: -1em;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 0.5em;
}
```

Above HTML code does not create `class="done"` on click action, when launched on  browser.

On [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1wgz8rx/) the same code works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the code is included in `<head>` it is executed before the content of the `<body>` is loaded. So, the elements are not found in the *DOM* when binding events and event is not bound.

There are **two ways** to solve this problem.

1. **Wrap the code in `DOMContentLoaded`** event callback.

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       var list = document.querySelector('ul');
       list.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
           if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
               ev.target.classList.toggle('done');
           }
       }, false);
   });
   ```

   Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/pr2hw6c1/

   Read More about DOMContentLoaded: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded
2. **Move the code to the end of `<body>`**, so that when the script is executed, all the *DOM* elements are loaded.

**Note:** You can also use `load` event to execute the script code after *DOM* is *completely* loaded, but this will wait for all the resources(image, frames, etc.) on the page to load which is not necessary to bind the event on the elements. For reference read  [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and Load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)

---

> Why does the same code in jsfiddle works?

jsfiddle provides four options for where the script should be included. You can set this option from the left panel, below the libraries list.

1. `onLoad`: This is same as `load` event of window. The code is wrapped in the callback of the `load` event so, the functions/variables cannot be accessed from outside of it. Ex. From HTML inline handlers.
2. `onDomReady`: This is same as `DOMContentLoaded` or `ready` of jquery, here also the code is wrapped
3. `No wrap - in Head`: This means the JS code will be added in the `head`. `No wrap` means the code is not wrapped in any function like in `load` and `DOMContentLoaded`. So the functions/variables defined are global.
4. `No wrap - in Body`: The script is loaded at the end of `<body>` element.

Now that we know how the script behaves for each of the option, in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k1wgz8rx/), the option for script location is set to `onLoad`, so the code works. The code will work for all options except `No wrap - in Head`.

Read more about this on jsfiddle docs http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#fiddle-settings-sidebar

Comment: MDN says, *The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.* So, one is building a responsive webpage.

Comment: @overexchange The main words to note are **initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed**, as the elements on which event to be bound is loaded, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the script tag and putting it at the very end of the body. They way it is now, the script is trying to run before the elements on the page are loaded. Moving the script tag to the bottom of the body will ensure that all the html elements above it have loaded properly.