# What is missing in my code

Tags: javascript

Why this code is not working ?
I think i am doing some silly mistake here.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var text = "Planing";
  document.getElementsByTagName("div").innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="eg"></div>
```

Comment: "Why this code is not working?" How is this code supposed to be working?

Comment: You could try, switching the getElementsByTagName to getElementsById and tag the 'demo' instead. That may help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of all the matching elements(`<div>`s in this case) on the page/DOM, to select first element use array notation with zero index.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var text = "Planing";
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="eg"></div>
```

If you want to select first element, you can use `document.querySelector('div');`

If you want to perform some operation on all the selected elements, you need to iterate over them.

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    allDivs[i].innerHTML = 'Div ' + i;
}
```

Comment: @akash Check updated fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ushqasq7/2/, this is because how jsfiddle includes script in page, I've selected the option to `no wrap`, if you select it to `onLoad` or `contentLoaded` the script is added inside the respective handler

Comment: @akash For more information on how it works on jsfiddle please see bottom part http://stackoverflow.com/a/32925927/2025923

Answer (score 2):

getElement**s**ByTagName, as the name suggests returns an array of elements (even if there is just one). You need to access the first one before applying the text.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var text = "Planing";
  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML = text;
});
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="eg"></div>
```

Comment: I didn't copy and paste. I clicked on "copy snippet to answer" from OP's question and fixed it... I just realised now, after refreshing the page, that someone else beat me to posting another answer first.