# prevent default is not working in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

I am trying to add `preventDefault()` for a function as below :

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="makePaid" onclick="makePaidModalView(1, evnt)">Make Paid</a>
```

Javascript:

```
function makePaidModalView(id, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(id);
}
```

But it is not alerting anything. Console says `ReferenceError: e is not defined`. How do I add the `preventDefault()` in this function ?

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/8g8oemcv/)

Comment: I need to pass `id` in that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `No wrap` option from Jsfiddle Left panel, by selecting this option will make the function `makePaidModalView` global, otherwise it'll be wrapped inside `load` or `DOMContentLoded` callback and cannot be accessed from HTML.
2. Use `event` as the name of the event parameter from the event handler. As `evnt` is not defined, `undefined` will be passed to the function and error will be thrown when trying to access method on `undefined.`
3. It is better practice not to use inline events. Use `addEventListener` to bind events on an element from Javascript.
4. If you have jQuery loaded on the page, you can use jQuery's `on` method to bind events.
5. Use `data-*` custom attributes to store the data related to an element on the element itself. You can access this from JS by using `data('dataName')`.

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/8g8oemcv/2/)

```js
function makePaidModalView(id, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //console.log(id)
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="makePaid" onclick="makePaidModalView(1, event)">Make Paid</a>
```

---

Using jQuery `on` with `data-*` custom attribute to store data on element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#makePaid').on('click', function(e) {
    alert($(this).data('id'));
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="makePaid" data-id="1">Make Paid</a>
```

**Sidenote:** You can also use `return false;` from the event handler when using jQuery to prevent default action of the element and also stop the event from bubbling up the DOM.

Comment: To know more about jsfiddle options see bottom part  of http://stackoverflow.com/a/32925927/2025923

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to bind your function on particular event. Something like

```js
document.getElementById('makePaid').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  makePaidModalView(this.dataset.id, event);
});

function makePaidModalView(id, e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="makePaid" data-id=1>Make Paid</a>
```

Comment: The parameter `1` here is hardcoded/static, to make it more dynamic/flexible use `data-*` attribute to store id on element, check the second code snippet in my example for the reference of how to use `data-*` attribute

Comment: Yeah we can do this, Updated the answer now.