# Alternative for using body onload

Tags: javascript, html, function, onload

I'm a newbie and i'm playing around trying to achieve something using javascript.

I have a function which i need to take effect once my page loads but i don't want to use `<body onload="init()"` is there another alternative?

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function init() {
            container = document.createElement('div');
            <script>

            <body onload="init()">

            </body>
```

Comment: You can use jQuery, and use the $(document).ready(handler) function, which will execute the function handler when the DOM is loaded.

Comment: You should make it happend right in your javascript. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and Load events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)

Comment: @ZachPerkitny - the document ready is a different event than window.load and is fired earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:

```
window.onload = function() {
 init();
}
```

Comment: You can, but that's very poor form, it will wipe out any onload event handler already set.

Comment: Since this is on load hence nothing is wiped out. But off course the better approach is window.addEventListener("load", init);

Comment: window.addEventListener("load", init); this worked for me. But now I need to add this to a magento site m working on but its not displayig. I checked the source code and i can see the codes there anyhelp?

Answer (score 10):

Call it from a `load` handler:

```
function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');

  // ...
}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',init);` is another solution that you can use. Check this [Test runner](http://jsperf.com/onload-vs-domcontentloaded/5#runner) for performance

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use jquery, but you have to include it in your head manaully or with

```
<!-- Google CDN -->

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

if you want to use Google CDN, or

```
<!-- Microsoft CDN -->

<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

for Microsoft CDN.
Now, you can use jquery in your webpage. So write in your head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).on('load",function(){
   // your code
 });
</script>
```

Of course, you need to know how to use jquery to use this solution. However, you can use javasript too, but I suggest you to start learning jquery: is very useful.

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() { 
    //your code
  }
</script>
```

This should be the right way ;)

REALLY IMPORTANT: this functions are called when your document is starting loading! If you want to apply something at the end of the loading of the page (better solution to improve loading speed) use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //your code
});
```

in jquery, or

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //your code
});
```

in javascript

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ `is NOT the same as `$(window).on('load",function(){` the latter fires later

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Well... it works really well too, doesn't it? EDIT: I'm adjusting EDIT2: updated, thank you for your feedback: I wouldn't notice that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events  - not saying in practice it is not better but here the OP asks for a replacement for the `onload` handler

Comment: okk, found the right alternative: window.onload = function() {}, isn't it?

Comment: same as `window.addEventListener("load", init);` as far as event it handles

Comment: perfect ;) if you find my answer complete and useful, please rate it positive. I'm new in this comunity and I don't have a great reputation at the moment (and a big knowledge of english too :D )

Answer (score -3):

I am new in programming but i think u can do something like this:
With Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // code loaded..
});
```

Without Jquery

```
// this code is bad to practise
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            // Put your code here
        }
        window.onload = init;
    </script>
```

Comment: `$(document).function(){  ` is a syntax error, the second `window.onload` is not a good practice