# Check if jQuery has loaded with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am adding jQuery in dynamically due to the requirements of my project. However, when the below function is called `jQuery is not defined` is displayed in the console. However, if I write `alert(jQuery)` in the console it returns `function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}`, so I know that it is loaded. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
function AddExternals(){
  if (!jQuery){
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    console.log("Added jQuery!");
  } else {
    console.log("jQuery already exists.")
  }
}
```

Comment: How is `AddExternals()` is called? Remember, you're checking for `jQuery` after the DOM has completely loaded.

Comment: I am checking using `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", AddExternals)`

Comment: Switch to `window.onload = function() { AddExternals() };`

Comment: How is the console displaying `jQuery is not defined`? you must be calling something else which relies on it as your `console.log()` in the code you shared doesn't say that anywhere - I'm guessing you're calling something after this?

Comment: ... That's the error I receive in the console... I am calling nothing else anywhere at that point in time. It's triggered by `if (!jQuery){`.

Comment: Maybe check for Require.js or Browserify.

Comment: You can check https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.jQuery` to validate if jQuery has been loaded or not

```
function AddExternals(){
  if (!window.jQuery){
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    console.log("Added jQuery!");
  } else {
    console.log("jQuery already exists.")
  }
}

AddExternals();
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sSBmbmuOqcKnyWJ4B1MM?p=preview)

Note: According to js convention pascal case is used when it is a constructor function .For example

```
var adder = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a + b');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load in certain moment(not right after page load), make some function like this.

It checks script load binding event.

```js
function loadFile(url, callback) {
    var d = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var s = document.createElement("script");

    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = url;
    s.charset = "utf-8";
    d.appendChild(s);

    if(callback) {
        if(s.addEventListener) {
            s.onload = callback;
        } else if(s.readyState) {
            s.onreadystatechange = function() {
                s.readyState === "loaded" && callback();
            };
        }
    }
}

// load JS file dynamically.
loadFile("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js", function() {
  // it will call right after file has been loaded
  alert(jQuery.fn.jquery);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this way, instead of using `(!jQuery)`:

```
if (typeof jQuery == "undefined") {
```

Comment: Even if jQuery has been loaded it still runs as if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414766/2151050)

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the document has been
>   completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images,
>   and subframes to finish loading (the load event can be used to detect
>   a fully-loaded page).

So, move move your function to `window.onload` event

```
window.onload = function() { 
   AddExternals() 
};
```

And go with Praveen's advice.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you have to use a timer to check after appending a script:

```
function AddExternals(){

  var timer;

  if (!jQuery){
    var jq = document.createElement("script");
    jq.type = "text/javascript";
    jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jq);
    console.log("Added jQuery!");
  }else{
    console.log("jQuery already exists.")
  }

  timer = setInterval(checkIfjqLoaded, 1000);

  function checkIfjqLoaded(){
     if(timer){
       clearInterval(timer);
       AddExternals();
     }
  }

}
```