# Body onLoad not working if a script tab is included inside body

Tags: javascript, html

**Summary:**
Following body onload works when a link to another script using `<script>` is included in the head tag but not while the same `<script>` is included just before the end of body

```
<body onload="console.log('body loaded');">
```

**To Reproduce:**

Load Complete code in [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pathrik/r1ekhfu0/)

When we set the Javascript Loadtype to No Wrap - In `<head>`, we see the following logs in the console:

```
DOM Loaded
window loaded
body loaded
```

But when we set it to No Wrap - In `<body>`, we see the following logs in the console:

```
DOM Loaded
window loaded
```

Why the difference?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Comment: You have not posted the code that is not working, not even in your fiddle .

Comment: If you load the same html in your webpage, the `'body loaded'` will be printed. I sense this is an issue with jsfiddle

Comment: *"Following script tag"* - You don't show a script tag.

Comment: @bigΩmega I tried the same in Chrome and the behavior is same i.e., 'body loaded' is not getting printed when the script tag is added just before the closing body tag :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting it in body tag needs to wait for all the resources to be rendered in page such as images, styles, scripts etc.

When you put it inside **head** tag, no need to wait for the resources to be rendered.

It's like between window.on('load') and document.ready in jquery.

Comment: But regardless js console will always be ready to be used, at any point. DOM load shouldn't block that