# Setting input to focus using onload

Tags: javascript, html

I have to set price to be focused when the page using onload.

```
<body style="border: solid 1px black; margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;width: 500px;">
    <form>
        <fieldset style="margin:25px";><legend>Discount Calculator</legend>
            <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: 25%;">
            <label>Enter Price: <input onload = "thing()" type="text" name="price" id="price"></label><br><br>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function thing()
        {
            document.focus()
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

I know I am doing something wrong. I can easily set this to be focused by using `document.findElementById("price").focus()`, but for this assignment I need to do it as onload. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try `window.onload=function(){}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking setting the focus, here is what you could do.

Also, it might be worth a read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events) on what are the different load events and meaning.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#price").focus();
});
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" name="dummy-1">
  <input type="text" name="dummy-2">
  <fieldset style="margin:25px" ;>
    <legend>Discount Calculator</legend>
    <div style="text-align: right; margin-right: 25%;">
      <label>Enter Price:
        <input onload="thing()" type="text" name="price" id="price">
      </label>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="text" name="dummy-1">
  <input type="text" name="dummy-2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Do stuff...
}, false );
```

It is an analogue of

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // Do stuff...
});
```

written in pure Javascript without jQuery. And one more option is to use

```
window.onload = function() {
  // Do stuff...
}
```

thanks @mplungjan for this idea.

Comment: window.onload=function(){} as commented is more an analoque and more compatible