# iFrame onLoad waits until image inside loads

Tags: javascript, image, iframe, dom-events

I have an iFrame with onLoad event attached, inside the iFrame I have an image with src pointing to some PHP file. I'm loading the image async but still my iFrame onload waits for the image load and fires it after that. Can someone explain why? and Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: It could help people to answer if you provide the implementation rather than a high level description.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Comment: @Luke Try this link in "Disable Cache" mode and you will notice the iFrame onload event(which makes the iFrame visible) fired only when the asyn image url call completes.. http://saravan-dev.jivox.com/ifrm1.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between DOMContentLoaded and load events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events)