# How to make script loading not block the browser loading indicator

Tags: javascript, html

When I include a script whose loading fails with a timeout (e.g. via packets being dropped, such as the Chinese Great Firewall dropping all packets to Google Analytics), the browser favicon loading indicator keeps spinning until the timeout is over.

(Note on Linux, you can simulate such timeouts using `iptables`, e.g. `sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -d 'IP_OF_GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_HERE' -j DROP`.)

**How do I have to place/annotate a `<script>` so that it does not block the loading indicator?**

I have tried various combinations (see articles [here](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/09/building-the-dom-faster-speculative-parsing-async-defer-and-preload/) and [here](https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/#async-and-defer)) of the `defer` and `async` attributes of `<script>` in `<head>` and `<body>`, but the spinner keeps spinning in my Chromium 68 and Firefox 63 Nightly.

Also, what exactly determines whether the spinner is shown or not? Is `DOMContentLoaded` the boundary, or are other things at play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it: [the `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

> fired when a resource and its dependent resources have finished loading

That is when the spinner stops, after the red "load" line in the Chromium *Network* tab.

```
// `load` so that this doesn't block the favicon loading indicator
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.async = true;
  script.src = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
});
```

Comment: well, with onready I meant  `load` or `DOMContentLoaded`, have you tested `DOMContentLoaded` and didn't work?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/2414783/6121568

Comment: @Emeeus Yes, I have tested `DOMContentLoaded` and it didn't work (as mentioned in my comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51985782/how-to-make-script-loading-not-block-the-browser-loading-indicator/51994877?noredirect=1#comment90939160_51987971). Should it? I guess it makes sense that `ready` is what makes the spinner stop?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. It seems like a feature that browsers could implement in different ways.