# Window is not defined in Next.js React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my **[Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)** app I can't seem to access `window`:

> Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): window is not defined

```
componentWillMount() {
    console.log('window.innerHeight', window.innerHeight);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Move the code to componentDidMount() which is only executed on the client where with `window` is available. Besides, `componentWillMount()` is being [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) in v17https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ#i-use-a-library-which-throws-window-is-undefined

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Move the code from `componentWillMount()` to [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('window.innerHeight', window.innerHeight);
}
```

In Next.js, `componentDidMount()` is executed only on the client where `window` and other browser specific APIs will be available. From the [Next.js wiki](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ#i-use-a-library-which-throws-window-is-undefined):

> Next.js is universal, which means it executes code first server-side,
> then client-side. The window object is only present client-side, so if
> you absolutely need to have access to it in some React component, you
> should put that code in componentDidMount. This lifecycle method will
> only be executed on the client. You may also want to check if there
> isn't some alternative universal library which may suit your needs.

Along the same lines, `componentWillMount()` will be [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) in v17 of React, so it effectively will be potentially unsafe to use in the very near future.

Answer (score 253):

̶A̶n̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶y̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶`p̶r̶o̶c̶e̶s̶s̶.̶b̶r̶o̶w̶s̶e̶r` ̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶e̶x̶e̶c̶u̶t̶e̶ ̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶d̶u̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶r̶e̶n̶d̶e̶r̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶l̶i̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶s̶i̶d̶e̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶.

But `process` object has been deprecated in Webpack5 and also NextJS, because it is a NodeJS variable for backend side only.

So we have to use back `window` object from the browser.

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // Client-side-only code
}
```

Other solution is by using react hook to replace `componentDidMount`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    // Client-side-only code
})
```

Comment: this approach is now already being **deprecated**   https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5354#issuecomment-520305040

Comment: You mean `typeof window !== "undefined"`, because otherwise it is serverside run

Comment: seriously, that guy needs to edit his comment

Comment: @Robbie - I got the other "guy" to edit the comment.

Comment: I've been developing a website in react all day. First project too and I was stuck on this all day. Thanks

Comment: why "undefined" as a string - I'm used to do this: `type(...) == list` which is python code - so typeof ... returns a string but why a string?

Comment: @france1 you can check the return value of typeof from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof. I believe it is to avoid confusion, so they just return string undefined.

Comment: useEffect hook works.

Comment: I've crafted an actual complete answer below, with the different patterns you can use depending on the situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/77556387/5513532

Answer (score 113):

If you use **React Hooks** you can move the code into the [Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

```js
import * as React from "react";

export const MyComp = () => {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // window is accessible here.
    console.log("window.innerHeight", window.innerHeight);
  }, []);

  return (<div></div>)
}
```

The code inside `useEffect` is only executed on the client (in the browser), thus it has access to `window`.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do it properly in a react functional component.

Comment: This works although if you are doing something inside useEffect that updates state make sure to add an empty `[]` as deps.

Answer (score 90):

With No SSR

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)

function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      <p>HOME PAGE is here!</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: This one works even if the library is accessing 'window' while is imported

Comment: how to access the variable from external js? like var myVar = "bla"

Comment: @bl4ckck unfortunately you can only use dynamic import on component (and not functions)

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`

Comment: This works, but it is not a good approach if initial loading time is concerned. With `no SSR`, the website initial loading time is increased. Hence, SEO is badly impacted, as an SEO expert, I would not recommend this

Answer (score 30):

The error occurs because window is not yet available, while component is still mounting. You can access window object after component is mounted.

You can create a very useful hook for getting dynamic `window.innerHeight` or `window.innerWidth`

```
const useDeviceSize = () => {

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const handleWindowResize = () => {
    setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    setHeight(window.innerHeight);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // component is mounted and window is available
    handleWindowResize();
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
    // unsubscribe from the event on component unmount
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize);
  }, []);

  return [width, height]

}

export default useDeviceSize
```

Use case:

```
const [width, height] = useDeviceSize();
```

Comment: Clever. Very nice.

Comment: It will work every time when you resize the window, it is useful in cases when you are working with css -> to make your pages responsive

Comment: awesome solution. generic and reusable across everywhere

Comment: @user884321 it will print correct width and height from the first render. You can check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-water-575xy6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @IsmoilShokirov https://prnt.sc/2w7vA1Ga2IIv ?

Comment: this returns 0 as window width/height on initial call which can cause unexpected behaviour. i have provided an answer to this question below which fixes this problem.

Answer (score 16):

`global?.window && window.innerHeight`

It's important to use the operator `?.`, otherwise the build command might crash.

Comment: That helped me in my React App in Hooks. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

`componentWillMount()` lifecycle hook works both on server as well as client side. In your case server would not know about `window` or `document` during page serving, the suggestion is to move the code to either

**Solution 1:**

```js
componentDidMount()
```

**Or, Solution 2**

In case it is something that you only want to perform in then you could write something like:

```js
componentWillMount() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        console.log('window.innerHeight', window.innerHeight);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

A bit late but you could also consider using [Dynamic Imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) from `next` turn off `SSR` for that component.

You can warp the import for your component inside a dynamic function and then, use the returned value as the actual component.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const BoardDynamic = dynamic(() => import('../components/Board.tsx'), {
  ssr: false,
})
```

```
<>
   <BoardDynamic />
</>
```

Comment: Heads up, in the current version of nextJS it's `ssr`, not `SSR`

Answer (score 11):

Best solution ever

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const Chart = dynamic(()=> import('react-apexcharts'), {
    ssr:false,
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Does this mean that this page is gonna get rendered in the browser instead of server ? for me the whole purpose of using  next js is rendering in server

Comment: Yes, because when generating static html content for our sites, there are no window/screen global objects we can access.

Answer (score 10):

In the constructor of your class *Component* you can add

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    global.window = {}
}
```

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class MyClassName extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        ...
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            global.window = {}
        }
}
```

This will avoid the error (in my case, the error would occur after I would click reload of the page).

Comment: is there any documentation on `global`?

Comment: I'd highly recommend against this approach. Setting `global.window` on the server-side will not behave the same as the actual `window` object provided in the browser environment.

Comment: Though this will avoid the error at hand on the client, it will create others you likely won't see or find very easily. To future travelers, heed @juliomalves' advice and avoid this approach.

Answer (score 8):

I have to access the hash from the URL so I come up with this

```js
const hash = global.window && window.location.hash;
```

Comment: the neatest solution yet

Comment: this solution works too, also you could just define it inside useEffect()

Answer (score 5):

Here's an easy-to-use workaround that I did.

```
const runOnClient = (func: () => any) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    if (window.document.readyState == "loading") {
      window.addEventListener("load", func);
    } else {
      func();
    }
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
runOnClient(() => {
// access window as you like
})

// or async
runOnClient(async () => {
// remember to catch errors that might be raised in promises, and use the `await` keyword wherever needed
})
```

This is better than just `typeof window !== "undefined"`, because if you just check that the window is not undefined, it won't work if your page was redirected to, it just works once while loading. But this workaround works even if the page was redirected to, not just once while loading.

Comment: This will override  window.onload every time

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic nope, if you can see it sets `window.onload` only if the page is not loaded.

Comment: consider this snippet `runOnClient(f1); runOnClient(f2)`

Comment: also read about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Comment: @OwnageIsMagic I made it append the listener, I hope it is fixed now.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue when refreshing the page (caused by an import that didn't work well with SSR).

What fixed it for me was going to pages where this was occurring and forcing the import to be dynamic:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';


const SomeComponent = dynamic(()=>{return import('../Components/SomeComponent')}, {ssr: false});

//import SomeComponent from '../Components/SomeComponent'
```

Commenting out the original import and importing the component dynamically forces the client-side rendering of the component.

The dynamic import is covered in Nextjs's documentation here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import

I got to this solution by watching the youtube video here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DA0ie1RPP6g

Answer (score 5):

I wrapped the general solution (`if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;`) in a custom hook, that I am very pleased with. It has a similiar interface to reacts `useMemo` hook which I really like.

```js
import { useEffect, useMemo, useState } from "react";

const InitialState = Symbol("initial");

/**
 *
 * @param clientFactory Factory function similiar to `useMemo`. However, this function is only ever called on the client and will transform any returned promises into their resolved values.
 * @param deps Factory function dependencies, just like in `useMemo`.
 * @param serverFactory Factory function that may be called server side. Unlike the `clientFactory` function a resulting `Promise` will not be resolved, and will continue to be returned while the `clientFactory` is pending.
 */
export function useClientSideMemo<T = any, K = T>(
  clientFactory: () => T | Promise<T>,
  deps: Parameters<typeof useMemo>["1"],
  serverFactory?: () => K
) {
  const [memoized, setMemoized] = useState<T | typeof InitialState>(
    InitialState
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      setMemoized(await clientFactory());
    })();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, deps);

  return typeof window === "undefined" || memoized === InitialState
    ? serverFactory?.()
    : memoized;
}
```

**Usage Example:**

I am using it to dynamically import libaries that are not compatible with **SSR** in next.js, since its own [dynamic import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) is only compatible with components.

```js
  const renderer = useClientSideMemo(
    async () =>
      (await import("@/components/table/renderers/HighlightTextRenderer"))
        .HighlightTextRendererAlias,
    [],
    () => "text"
  );
```

As you can see I even implemented a fallback factory callback, so you may provide a result when initially rendering on the server aswell. In all other aspects this hook should behave similiar to reacts `useMemo` hook. Open to feedback.

Answer (score 4):

### Next JS 13 with Pages router

Below is a code snippet on how you can create, update(use create fn for updating as well), and remove a key (here `username`) from `localStorage`

```js
const [username, setUsername] = useState<null | string>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("username");
    setUsername(token);
  }
}, [setUsername]);

const createItem = (newUsername: string) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("username", newUsername);

    let token = localStorage.getItem("username");

    setUsername(token);
  }
};

const removeItem = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.removeItem("username");
    setUsername(null);
  }
};

console.log(username, "username");
```

[Reference](https://articles.wesionary.team/using-localstorage-with-next-js-a-beginners-guide-7fc4f8bfd9dc)

Answer (score 3):

**I was facing the same problem when i was developing a web application in next.js** This fixed my problem, you have to refer to refer the window object in a life cycle method or a react Hook. For example lets say i want to create a store variable with redux and in this store i want to use a windows object i can do it as follows:

```
let store
useEffect(()=>{
    store = createStore(rootReducers,   window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && 
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
 }, [])
 ....
```

So basically, when you are working with window's object always use a hook to play around or `componentDidMount()` life cycle method

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers here is fully complete and most people will end up here because they hit the same issue but in various situations that require different solutions, so let me share the summary extracted from my [paid course on the topic](https://course.nextjspatterns.com/manage-client-only-code-in-next-js-with-react-browser-components). I've also written a [more detailed and free article](https://medium.com/@eric.burel/how-to-get-rid-of-window-is-not-defined-and-hydration-mismatch-errors-in-next-js-567cc51b4a17).

Original question mentions an older version of React, using callbacks, but my answer is based on hooks and more relevant to current versions of React (16+) and Next (12+).

My component needs a browser-only library like Leaflet or jQuery, it crashes on server import

These libraries crash when being imported server-side, because they expect th window object to be immediately available.

[This is a situation similar to the one described in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73679783/window-not-defined-or-document-not-defined-when-importing-module-in-next-js)

You need what I call a Browser Component, a React component that cannot be prerendered on the server, contrary to Client components that are prerendered on the server in Next/React.

Solution: use lazy loading with [next/dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading) and `ssr: false` to import your Browser Component. Now your component will only be imported and run in the browser.

My component needs to use the window object or any other browser-only code to render. Sadly, I cannot modify its code.

It's a Browser Component. Ideally, it should be rewritten to be a Client Component, but since you can't control the code you may not be able to do that.

You can use a `NoSsr` component. You can also use the [`useMounted hook`](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) (Next doc calls it "useClient") in the parent, but only if the parent is a Client Component. So `NoSsr` is a better choice in this case.

Relevant utility code:

```js
export const useMounted = () => {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState<boolean>()
    // effects run only client-side
    // so we can detect when the component is hydrated/mounted
    // @see https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect
    useEffect(() => {
        setMounted(true)
    }, [])
    return mounted
}

export function NoSsr({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const mounted = useMounted();
  if (!mounted) return null;
  return <>{children}</>;
}
```

My component needs to use the window object or any other browser-only code to render. I can modify its code.

The component should be a Client Component. Make it safe to be prerendered on the server

You can use the `useMounted` hook above to rewrite your component and render conditionally: you can use the `window` object to render only if the component is mounted.

This will turn your "Browser Component" into a "Client Component" that is safe for server-side rendering, even if renders nothing server-side or a loader.

### My component needs a library that can be imported server-side but not used there like D3.

More broadly, this is the case where you want to do imperative modification of the DOM, and the closest to OP original question.

Make it a Client Component.

You can wrap offending code in an effect like so: `useEffect(() => { console.log(window.innerHeight) }, [])`.

It will log/render nothing, or a loader, during server-side rendering, but that's totally fine.

My component code is exactly the same, but behaves slightly differently in browser and server.

This happens when using dates or localization features of JavaScript, you have the same code client-side and server-side but it generates a different result.

It should be a client component.

You can use suppressHydrationWarning or a Suspense as demonstrated in [this article](https://francoisbest.com/posts/2023/displaying-local-times-in-nextjs)

Answer (score 1):

For such cases, Next.js has [Dynamic Import](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import).

A module that includes a library that only works in the browser, it's suggested to use Dynamic Import. [Refer](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr)

Answer (score 1):

**Date: 06/08/2021**

Check if the window object exists or not and then follow the code along with it.

```js
 function getSelectedAddress() {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;

    // Some other logic
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Next.js version 12.1.0, I find that we can use `process.title` to determine whether we are in `browser` or in `node` side. Hope it helps!

```
export default function Projects(props) {
    console.log({ 'process?.title': process?.title });

    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}
```

**1. From the terminal**, I receive `{ 'process?.title': 'node' }`

[image: process.title === 'node']

**2. From Chrome devtool**, I revice `{ 'process?.title': 'browser' }`

[image: process.title === 'browser']

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code snippet for use-cases such as - **to get current pathname (CurrentUrl Path)**

```
 import { useRouter } from "next/router";

 const navigator = useRouter()
 console.log(navigator.pathname);
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can add the 'use client' directive at the top of your client side component.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive

Answer (score 0):

You can define a state var and use the window event handle to handle changes like so.

```
const [height, setHeight] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    if (!height) setHeight(window.innerHeight - 140);
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        setHeight(window.innerHeight - 140);
    });
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who somehow cannot use hook (for example, function component):

Use `setTimeout(() => yourFunctionWithWindow());` will allow it get the window instance. Guess it just need a little more time to load.

Comment: Actually, besides being not nice code and maybe have to use state to get it working, it did not work for me, still getting window not defined. Node has it's own setTimeout-definition which doesn't know the window object
I solved with 'use client' and binding this to the function

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts, using useEffect is only working if you define your function within it.
But I don't want to define helper functions there, so I ended up doing it like this:

```
    'use client'
    const MyClientC = () => { 
    const desiredCalculation = helperFN.bind(this)
       ...
    }
    // helperFN.ts
    interface Window {
      innerHeight: number
      ...
    
    }
    const isBrowser = () => typeof window !== 'undefined';
    let Window: Window = {} as Window;
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      Window = window;
    }
    
    const helperFn = () => {     
        if (!isBrowser()) {
          return false;
        }
        return Window.innerHeight ...
```

Maybe this helps

Answer (score 0):

**Solution when using hooks.** Credit to [@luckgaer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72089060/11395152).

This hook will return null on initial(server) render when called in a client component, and therefore not throw the above stated error.
All we have to do to utilize the hook in a client component is to check that it's not null and skip its usage on its first render. Example on how to use the hook in a client component is below the hook snippet.

```
"use client";
import { useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

const useWindowWidth = (): number | null => {
  if (!global?.window) return null;
  const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let timeoutId: NodeJS.Timeout;

    const handleResize = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        setWindowWidth(window.innerWidth);
      }, 100);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowWidth;
};

export default useWindowWidth;
```

How to use in client components:

```
const windowWidth = useWindowWidth();
if (windowWidth && windowWidth >= 850)...
```

Answer (score 0):

## Current answer as per next 13

In my case I was importing a library that used `window` in it's source code without adhering to it's usage in nextjs environments.

The error in such scenarios occurs because next13 tries to pre-render your pages and while doing so when they parse their code then obviously they will raise the error belonging to class `things on the browser are not defined on the server`.

Easy way to solve this is to tell nextjs not to pre-render that page. Simply opt out. In order to do that from your `page.tsx` export `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";` which omits this page from pre-rendering.

Another way would be to raise an issue and patch the source code yourself to then create a PR to be merged.

### Final code

```
import React from "react";

function page() {
    return (
        <div> {/*tsx/jsx*/} </div>
    );
}

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
export default page;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put      'use client' on the top of ur codebase

Answer (score -1):

I want to leave this approach that I found interesting for future researchers. It's using a custom hook [useEventListener](https://usehooks.com/useEventListener/) that can be used in so many others needs.

Note that you will need to apply a little change in the originally posted one, like I suggest [here](https://gist.github.com/gragland/ae701852ae6159c712d860a946cd7ca0#gistcomment-3979378).

So it will finish like this:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

export const useEventListener = (eventName, handler, element) => {
  const savedHandler = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    savedHandler.current = handler
  }, [handler])

  useEffect(() => {
    element = !element ? window : element
    const isSupported = element && element.addEventListener
    if (!isSupported) return

    const eventListener = (event) => savedHandler.current(event)

    element.addEventListener(eventName, eventListener)

    return () => {
      element.removeEventListener(eventName, eventListener)
    }
  }, [eventName, element])
}
```

Answer (score -3):

If it is NextJS app and inside ***_document.js***, use below:

```
<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: `
            var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
        `
        }} />
```