# In React and Next.js constructor, I am getting "Reference Error: localstorage is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I make a system jsonwebtoken in React and use Next.js. I find a problem when I run the code in the browser, that is, *"localStorage is not defined"*. How can I fix it?

This is my code in file *AuthStudentContext.js*:

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const axiosReq = axios.create()
const AuthStudentContext = React.createContext()

export class AuthStudentContextProvider extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            students: [],
            student: localStorage.getItem('student') || {},
            token: localStorage.getItem('token') || "",
            isLoggedIn: (localStorage.getItem('student' == null)) ? false : true
        }
    }

    login = (credentials) => {
        return axiosReq.post("http://localhost:4000/api/login", credentials)
            .then(response => {
                const { token } = response.data
                localStorage.setItem("token", token)

                this.setState({
                    token,
                    isLoggedIn: true
                })

                return console.log(response)
            })
    }
```

And it shows error "localStorage is not defined".

Comment: use window.localStorage

Comment: and then window is not defined

Comment: can you post the snippet with error. window should be available in global namespace

Comment: Next is overriding the window object everywhere except component did mount. : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55151122/1643143

Comment: voting to reopen this as the question was been edited with more details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the `constructor`, as well as `componentWillMount` lifecycle hooks, the server is still rendering the component. On the other hand, [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) exists as part of the browser's *window* global, and thus you can only use it when the component is rendered. Therefore you can only access localStorage in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. Instead of calling localStorage in the constructor, you can define an empty state, and update the state in `componentDidMount` when you can start to call localStorage.

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
    students: [],
    student: undefined
    token: undefined,
    isLoggedIn: undefined
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.login();
  this.setState({
    student: localStorage.getItem('student') || {},
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || "",
    isLoggedIn: (localStorage.getItem('student' == null)) ? false : true
  });
}
```

Answer (score 29):

As everyone already mentioned, Next.js runs both on the client and server. On the server, there isn't any `localStorage`, hence the `undefined` error.

However, an alternative solution is to check if Next.js is running on the server before accessing the `localStorage`. I.e.,

```
const ISSERVER = typeof window === "undefined";

if(!ISSERVER) {
    // Access localStorage
    ...localStorage.get...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I never touched Next.js, but I guess its equivalent to [Nuxt.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuxt.js). So it does server-side rendering while you try to access localstorage on the client side.

You will need to use `componentDidMount()` for this. Here is an example:

```
componentDidMount(){
   localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
   alert("Tom is in the localStorage");
}
```

Otherwise, you could try with `process.browser`:

```
if (process.browser) {
   localStorage.setItem("token", token);
}
```

Comment: i don't want setItem, but i want getItem

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what [SILENT said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540321/in-react-and-next-js-constructor-i-am-getting-reference-error-localstorage-is/63663373#63663373), this works for me:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (localStorage) {
        const getLocalState = localStorage.getItem("headless");
        console.log("LocalState: ", getLocalState)
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: it will work only if your localstorage data is not depend with your initial browser data. if your browser data is depend with localstorage then it will give issue cause next js render on server side and local storage work for client side

Answer (score 3):

The *window* object and Localstorage won't be available when Next.js is building. So you need to check if the code is running in the browser. If you are running in React hooks you don't need to do this because hooks are always running browser side in React.

Just add these two utility functions to your Next.js project.

```
export const isBrowser = (): boolean => {
  return typeof window !== 'undefined'
}

export const nextLocalStorage = (): Storage | void => {
  if (isBrowser()) {
    return window.localStorage
  }
}
```

Then you can use it in your code like this:

```
nextLocalStorage()?.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working

```
export const Theme = { Light: "light", Dark: "dark" };

const [currentTheme, setCurrentTheme] = useState<string>();

  // Local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined" && currentTheme) {
      localStorage.setItem("theme", currentTheme);
    }
  }, [currentTheme]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentTheme(localStorage.getItem("theme") || Theme.Light);
  }, []);

  const siwtchTheme = () => {
    currentTheme === Theme.Light
      ? setCurrentTheme(Theme.Dark)
      : setCurrentTheme(Theme.Light);
  };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That's a lotta useEffect()!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function **getLocalStorageItem** and called this in **useEffect** with the required key name. After getting the value from localStorage, saved it in a state(i.e currentUser) and used it in initialState.

```
 const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState({});

  const getLocalStorageItem = (key) => {
    return typeof window !== undefined
      ? window.localStorage.getItem(key)
      : null;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentUser({
      token: getLocalStorageItem("token"),
      refreshToken: getLocalStorageItem("refreshToken"),
    });
  }, []);

  const initialState = {
    auth: {
      isLoggedIn: true,
      currentUser: currentUser,
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is only available client side. So Next.js will throw an error if you attempt to access localStorage to `getItem` or `setItem`.

Instead, inside the component, use a `useEffect` hook to access the `localStorage` on first client side render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("abc", "def");
}, []);
```