# Next.js: How to access localStorage?

Tags: javascript, authentication, local-storage, next.js

I'm currently working on my first member area with next.js. For now I want to store some data in localStorage (token, expiresAr, userInfo) - btw, later this is going to be stored in http-only cookie.

With the following code I get the error: "LocalStorage is not defined":

```js
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
   
   const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
   const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
   const expiresAt = localStorage.getItem("expiresAt");
   

  const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
    token,
    expiresAt,
    userInfo: userInfo ? JSON.parse(userInfo) : {},
  });

  const setAuthInfo = ({ token, userInfo, expiresAt }) => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
    localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
    localStorage.setItem("expiresAt", expiresAt);

    setAuthState({
      token,
      userInfo,
      expiresAt,
    });
  };
```

I already tried to use the following snipped:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
const expiresAt = localStorage.getItem("expiresAt");}
```

But with this code I get the error "token is undefined". So I tried to define the variables const token, const userInfo and const expiresAt globally. But then I get the error: "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1".

I'm a little stuck with this problem, so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: try to `console.log(token)` in `setAuthInfo` function, also go to `devtools->application->storage->local-storage` and check if anything is getting set over there. You might also net JSON.stringify the token inside the `setAuthInfo` if  its value not string

Comment: Thanks for your help! When go to devtools > aooplication > localStorage I can see the key-values of expiresAt, token and userInfo. Everything looks right to me. So the data are set in localStorage, but I am somehow not able to get them. Any ideas what I could try?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not trying to get this data on the backend (SSR)? What happens when you `console.log(localStorage.getItem("userInfo"))`, if you data is set properly it should be available directly on localStorage object like so, `localStorage.token`, if you `console.log(localStorage)` do you see the property that you set?

Comment: When I console.log(localStorage.getItem("userInfo")) I get the object with userInfo: something like this {"id": 17, "firstName": "e"} - this object I also see in localStorage and it matches my DB. 
When I console.log(localStorage) I get a longer string. Something like this: Storage {userInfo: "{"id":17,"firstName":"e"}", expiresAt: "1609183115", ally-supports-cache: "{"userAgent": ...}", token: "eyJhbGciO..", length: 4}. 
I'm really new in development - so yes, maybe there is a problem with SSR and CSR.

Comment: I found also found this - maybe this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540321/in-reactjs-and-nextjs-constructor-getting-reference-error-localstorage-is-not-d

Comment: I have not built any application with next.js, I have built apps on [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) I could use ` if (process.server) ` to make sure that code is rendered on server side, the opposite could be done like so `if (!process.server)`. They also hade a specific method for [data fetching](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching) on ssr for components. You should seek equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

After playing a little bit more with the code and with the help of you guys, I found the solution:

```js
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  let token = "";
  let userInfo = "";
  let expiresAt = "";

  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
    expiresAt = localStorage.getItem("expiresAt");
  }

...
```

The if-statement tells to run the code, when the window is available. I also had to define the variables (let token, let expiresAt and let userInfo) outside of the if-statement in order to be able to access them in other parts of the code.

Maybe this is helpful for somebody..

Answer (score 2):

This snippet should work

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const userInfo = localStorage.getItem("userInfo");
  const expiresAt = localStorage.getItem("expiresAt");
}
```

The reason you're getting the error `token is undefined` or `unexpected token` is because either there is no key `token` in your `localStorage` yet or your value is improperly set.

Comment: Thanks! I double checked everything - also with the help of @Andrius: in my devtools > Application > LocalStorage I can see the key-values of token, expiresAt and userInfo. Everything looks right. It seems to me as if I have set the items in localStorage, but I am unable to get them. I think this is because of next.js? Any ideas what I could try to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` hook runs on client side only. So, accessing storage inside it will guarantee that storage is defined. Here is a custom hook doing the work:

```
export default function useStorage(key, type = "sessionStorage") {
  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  // Initial fetch from storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const storage = type === "sessionStorage" ? sessionStorage : localStorage;
    setValue(storage.getItem(key));
  }, [key, type]);

  // Persist to storage
  useEffect(() => {
    // first render, don't override/destroy existing item value
    if (value !== undefined) {
      const storage = type === "sessionStorage" ? sessionStorage : localStorage;
      storage.setItem(key, value);
    }
  }, [key, value, type]);

  return [value, setValue];
}
```

Usage:

```
const [myValue, setMyValue] =  useStorage("my_value")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Next JS 13 with pages router

Below is the crux of how you can create/ remove/ update localStorage in Next JS.

```
const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    setToken(token);
  }
}, [setToken]);

const createToken = (newToken) => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.setItem("token", newToken);

    let token = localStorage.getItem("username");

    setToken(token);
  }
};

const removeToken = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage) {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    setToken(null);
  }
};

const logout = useCallback(() => {
  removeToken();
}, []);
```

[Reference](https://articles.wesionary.team/using-localstorage-with-next-js-a-beginners-guide-7fc4f8bfd9dc)

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider importing this component AuthProvider using dynamic imports and setting the option ssr to false,
Example

const AuthProvider=dynamic(()=>import("AuthProvider.tsx"),{ssr:false})

And using it normally as you would use this component elsewhere, just make sure it's dynamically imported. This worked for me.