# using client-side props in onclick function next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```js
class homeNotLoggedIn extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        function logout(){
            localStorage.clear()
            location.reload()
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="nav_bar">
                    <button id='logout' onClick={ logout() }>
```

Im stuck here because I can't move the function out of `componentDidMount` because I need localStorage and the location property from the client, I know its going to say "logout is not defined" but I do not know how do I define it in this case

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59540455/11667949

Comment: You can move the function to the class. The `onClick` event will always happen on the client-side where `window.localStorage` and `window.location` are set. Also, make sure to set the function as `onClick={this.logout}`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement something similar to [this](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps). You can get the location from getInitialProps/getStaticProps/getServerSideProps and then pass it as a prop to your component.