# Next.js, Zustand and loading initial state from the local storage

Tags: next.js, local-storage

In my Zustand store I try loading initial state from data persisted in Local storage (I did not opt for middle-ware as there were some kinks with Next that I didn't want to deal with):

```js
const getInitialProject = (): Project => {
    const project = loadCurrentProjectFromLs()

    return (
        project ?? {
            projectName: '',
            cards: [],
        }
    )
}

const useProjectStore = create<ProjectStore>((set, get) => ({
    ...getInitialProject(),
...
```

However the first render of page is done on server, not on the client ([In React and Next.js constructor, I am getting "Reference Error: localstorage is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59540321/in-react-and-next-js-constructor-i-am-getting-reference-error-localstorage-is)), which means that the local storage is not accessible at that time.

Which means that my code is not working properly, because the state can only be update after the first render, but the hooks that led to Zustand initialization are fired during the first render.

Is there a better way to tackle that problem than using `useEffect` hook that would update the store when localStorage becomes accessible? I would love the logic to be a part of the store, not the client, but I am unable to think of anything better than a loop with a timer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a top layout file with an useEffect that fires the loading function in the store when LS becomes available. This way the function is at least not part of pages, but broader infrastructure (the layout file).

```js
    const [hasInitializedStore, setHasInitializedStore] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!hasInitializedStore && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            loadCurrentProject()
            setHasInitializedStore(true)
        }
    }, [hasInitializedStore, loadCurrentProject])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use middleware to have persisted state. Try out [Persist and Sync](https://github.com/mayank1513/persist-and-sync) middleware that I created to solve a similar issue.

Install

```
$ pnpm add persist-and-sync
# or
$ npm install persist-and-sync
# or
$ yarn add persist-and-sync
```

And just add it to your state creator

```
import { create } from "zustand";
import { persistNSync } from "persist-and-sync";

type MyStore = {
    count: number;
    set: (n: number) => void;
};

const useStore = create<MyStore>(
    persistNSync(
        set => ({
            count: 0,
            set: n => set({ count: n }),
        }),
        { name: "my-channel" },
    ),
);
```

⚡Boom! Just a couple of lines and your state perfectly syncs between tabs/windows and it is also persisted using localStorage!

Answer (score -2):

Simply just put `use client` at the top of that component that you're trying to access that zustand hook. This indicates that the component is now client side obviously has access to localStorage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).