# react-simple-jstree with nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Can anyone give me idea on implementing react-simple-jstree with nextjs?

When I try to implement the same with reactjs it returns an error saying

> jQuery requires a window with a document

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window is not defined in NextJS React app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-nextjs-react-app)

Comment: I want my tree structure with jstree contextmenu structure using reactjs/nextjs.Screenshot as below:

Answer (score 0):

NextJS is server-side rendering, window is only available only in browser, so u need to disable SSR to load `react-simple-jstree`

```
const ReactJson = dynamic(() => import('react-simple-jstree'), { ssr: false });
```