# How do I set system preference dark mode in a react app but also allow users to toggle back and forth the current theme

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a react web app with a theme toggle on the navigation. I have a `ThemeProvider Context` that has logic to auto detects a user's System theme preference and sets it. However, I feel a user should be able to toggle themes back and forth on the website despite their system preference. Here is the `ThemeContext.js` file with all the theme logic including the `toggle` method.

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
    dark: false,
    toggle: () => {},
});

export default ThemeContext;

export function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
    // keeps state of the current theme
    const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);

    const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
        .matches;
    const prefersLight = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: light)')
        .matches;
    const prefersNotSet = window.matchMedia(
        '(prefers-color-scheme: no-preference)'
    ).matches;

    // paints the app before it renders elements
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        // Media Hook to check what theme user prefers
        if (prefersDark) {
            setDark(true);
        }

        if (prefersLight) {
            setDark(false);
        }

        if (prefersNotSet) {
            setDark(true);
        }

        applyTheme();

        // if state changes, repaints the app
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [dark]);

    // rewrites set of css variablels/colors
    const applyTheme = () => {
        let theme;
        if (dark) {
            theme = darkTheme;
        }
        if (!dark) {
            theme = lightTheme;
        }

        const root = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
        root.style.cssText = theme.join(';');
    };

    const toggle = () => {
        console.log('Toggle Method Called');

        // A smooth transition on theme switch
        const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.style.cssText = 'transition: background .5s ease';

        setDark(!dark);
    };

    return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider
            value={{
                dark,
                toggle,
            }}>
            {children}
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
}

// styles
const lightTheme = [
    '--bg-color: var(--color-white)',
    '--text-color-primary: var(--color-black)',
    '--text-color-secondary: var(--color-prussianBlue)',
    '--text-color-tertiary:var(--color-azureRadiance)',
    '--fill-switch: var(--color-prussianBlue)',
    '--fill-primary:var(--color-prussianBlue)',
];

const darkTheme = [
    '--bg-color: var(--color-mirage)',
    '--text-color-primary: var(--color-white)',
    '--text-color-secondary: var(--color-iron)',
    '--text-color-tertiary: var(--color-white)',
    '--fill-switch: var(--color-gold)',
    '--fill-primary:var(--color-white)',
];
```

So when the page loads, show the user's system preferred them but also allow user to toggle themes by clicking a toggle button that fires the `toggle` function. In my current code, when `toggle` is called, it seems that state changes occur twice and therefore theme remains unchanged. How do I ensure the `toggle` method works correctly?

Here is the [web app](https://itscosmas.me/) in question

Comment: I've finished answering your question, this should get you going :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the whole block of `useLayoutEffect` runs every the `dark` value changes. So when the user toggles `dark`, the `prefers...` if statements run and `setDark` back to the system preference.

To solve this you'll need to keep track of the user manually toggling the theme and then preventing the `prefers...` if statements from running.

In your `ThemeProvider` do the following:

- Add a state to monitor if the user has used toggle

```
const [userPicked, setUserPicked] = useState(false);
```

- Update your `toggle` function:

```
const toggle = () => {
  console.log('Toggle Method Called');

  const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  body.style.cssText = 'transition: background .5s ease';

  setUserPick(true) // Add this line
  setDark(!dark);
};
```

- Finally, update the `useLayout` to look like this:

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (!userPicked) { // This will stop the system preferences from taking place if the user manually toggles the them
    if (prefersDark) {
      setDark(true);
    }

    if (prefersLight) {
      setDark(false);
    }

    if (prefersNotSet) {
      setDark(true);
    }
  }

  applyTheme();
}, [dark]);
```

Your toggle component shouldn't have to change.

**Update:**

Sal's answer is a great alternative. Mine points out the flaw in existing code and how to add to it. This points out how to which your code more effectively.

```
export function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
  const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

  const [dark, setDark] = useState(prefersDark);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    applyTheme();
  }, [dark]);

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 6):

For everyone who wants to **subscribe to changes** of the system wide color scheme:

I extended @Daniel Danielecki's great answer:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const mq = window.matchMedia(
    "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
  );

  if (mq.matches) {
    setIsDark(true);
  }

  // This callback will fire if the perferred color scheme changes without a reload
  mq.addEventListener("change", (evt) => setIsDark(evt.matches));
}, []);
```

By adding an event listener to the media query, you can listen to changes in the dark theme. This is useful if your user has an adaptive dark/light mode cycle based on their current time.

Answer (score 4):

Although Barry's solution is working, note that instead of adding more code, you could achieve the same result by skimming it:

The key is to set the user's preference as initial state and stop checking it in the effect:

```js
export function ThemeProvider({ children }) {
    /* Because you are setting the initial theme to non-dark, 
    you can assume that your initial state should be dark only 
    when the user's preference is set to dark. */
    const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')
        .matches;

    // True if preference is set to dark, false otherwise.
    const [dark, setDark] = useState(prefersDark);
    /* Note: Initial state is set upon mounting, hence is better 
    to put the <ThemeProvider> up in your tree, close to the root <App> 
    to avoid unmounting it with the result of reverting to the default user 
    preference when and if re-mounting (unless you want that behaviour) */

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        /* You end up here only when the user takes action 
        to change the theme, hence you can just apply the new theme. */
        applyTheme();
}, [dark]);
...
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-saha-ln5iy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This is way cleaner and quite clever.

Comment: Hey, i have 2 css files (theme.css and theme-dark.css) ... how can i switch between these on the basis of system preference ... any idea ?

Comment: You can try the `media` attribute of `<link>` component.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media

<link href="..." media="prefers-color-scheme: light" />
<link href="..." media="prefers-color-scheme: dark" />

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use simply `useEffect`?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const prefersDark = window.matchMedia(
    "(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"
  ).matches;

  if (prefersDark) {
    setIsDark(true);
  }
}, []);
```

The reason to access `window` from `useEffect`: [Window is not defined in Next.js React app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app).