# creating initial state in context that depends on URL, window is not defined in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client-server, next.js

I'm trying to detect URL path inside my nextjs app and set the initial state based on the url path in the `context`, but am getting window is not defined. I know `window` won't be defined until client render but where would i put it if I want to pass initial state into context?

```js
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from "react";
import Reducer from './reducer'

const initialState = {
  'about': window.location.pathname == 'about' ? true : false
};

const Store = ({children}) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, initialState);


    return (
        <Context.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    )
};

export const Context = createContext(initialState);
export default Store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the `RouterContext`, You can make use of `pathname` value provided from it instead.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const Store = ({children}) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(Reducer, {
      about: router.pathname === '/about'
  });

  // rest of the logic

}
```

Comment: how could i do `export const Context = createContext(initialState);`, which is outside the component? initial state is inside the component so it's not defined outside of it

Comment: The default value for `createContext` is like a fallback when there is no provider. From react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext) "The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree". I don't think you need any initial value for created context here.

Comment: Great. I'm glad to help.

Comment: Including this, because there can be a very wrong interpretation of the comment above I made since I can't edit it anymore. It should be "The default value provided as an argument to `createContext` is like a fallback when there is no provider".

Answer (score 0):

`useReducer` has ability to do [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initialization) via a third argument. Perhaps you can dispatch an action in your component when window is available such as in [componentDidMount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-nextjs-react-app) or with hooks inside a `useEffect()`:

```
// set initial state, can also pass values here from dispatch also
// This would be called when `window` is available
function init() {
 return {
   'about': window.location.pathname == 'about' ? true : false
 };
}

// ...
// Some initial state
const initialState = { about: false };

// ..

useReducer(Reducer, initialState, init); // pass third argument, the init function
```

Then update your reducer to use init:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    // ...
    case 'init':
      return init(); // execute init function
  }
}
```

Finally trigger this new action type from your component using something like a useEffect hook:

```
// Assuming you are using context to get store state/dispatch
const [state, dispatch] = useContext(MyContext);
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: 'init' }); // could pass window values here also via payload perhaps
}, []);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, though `window` seems to still be undefined as well when used in `init()`, not sure why