# How to handle a back button click in a SPA?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, next.js

I'm developing a SPA with NextJS, and it's made out of exclusively one page. There's not `next/link` or Router usage whatsoever. The user would visit the page and everything would happen within the DOM, including all button click, view navigations, etc.

The problem that I'm facing right now, is that if the user at any point clicks the back button.. well, they'll leave the site.

I'd love to hear any suggestions that anyone has regarding this.

Comment: Lots of client side SPA's use hash based routing, which gives you some immunity from the default browser history by default.

Comment: In your site if your users habitually reach for the back button, then it would be best for the user experience to use client side routing

Comment: Are you working on the azure portal? :)

Comment: @KennyJohnJacob Yeah, I usually code with CSR, was looking to learn something new with Nextjs

Comment: If you’re using next.js without next.js routing, there’s no point in using next.js.

Answer (score 0):

The [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) can help you.

Example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return ''
}
```

Comment: Some error is throw? If the problem is the `window is not defined` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app)