# How to properly import library with no ssr - error: ... is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have the following import i would usually use:

```
import ASScroll from '@ashthornton/asscroll'
```

But since the library uses the window object, which isn't available server side, I need to dynamically load it with next.js.

Here's what I tried and how I need to use initialize it:

```
const {ASScroll} = dynamic(import('@ashthornton/asscroll'), {ssr: false})

const smoothScroll = new ASScroll({element: '.outer'})
```

I get the following error though:

> TypeError: ASScroll is not a constructor

Comment: The error indicates that you imported something else than ASScroll, as ASScroll.
Have you tried: ```const ASScroll = dynamic(import('@ashthornton/asscroll'), {ssr: false})```
?

Comment: @Master117 Yes, gives me the same error and my IDE then tells me: `Method expression is not of Function type` as well

Comment: Have you thought about loading that part on client side? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app

Comment: @Master117 That's what I tried with next/dynamic - have you thought another way?

Comment: Have you tried using componentDidMount() ?

Comment: @Master117 Ahh yes, I tried it within useEffect(), but apparently the import breaks it already - it points to: `> 1 | module.exports = require("@ashthornton/asscroll");
`

Comment: have you tried moving the import inside the useEffect? Not just the call to it.

Comment: @Master117 I think this would work, but I don't know how to properly get `ASScroll` when using inside of useEffect() with `import()`

Comment: import ASScroll from '@ashthornton/asscroll'
 should work inside useEffect

Comment: @Master117 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Comment: both import and export can happen at other parts as well in react.

Comment: @Master117 That's the error I get from the console, am using nextjs