# How to get page URL or hostname in NextJs Project?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hostname, domain-name, base-url

I want to get the page's full URL or site hostname like the image below on Static Site Generator.

I will try with `window.location.hostname`, but it doesn't work.

The error: **window not defined.**

[image]

Answer (score 43):

If you want the hostname inside getInitialProps on server side, still you can get it from req

```
Home.getInitialProps = async(context) => {
   const { req, query, res, asPath, pathname } = context;
   if (req) {
      let host = req.headers.host // will give you localhost:3000
     }
  }
```

Comment: It gives an error on build time https://prnt.sc/vyut51

Comment: Can u share the code block as i have shared, error shows 'replace' of undefined.

Comment: `getInitialProps` is discouraged since Next.js 9.3. Use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`

Comment: It throws error saying `cannot destructure property host of undefined`

Answer (score 36):

With server-side rendering (`getServerSideProps`), you can use `context.req.headers.host`:

```
import type { GetServerSideProps, NextPage } from "next";

type Props = { host: string | null };

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props> =
  async context => ({ props: { host: context.req.headers.host || null } });

const Page: NextPage<Props> = ({ host }) => <p>Welcome to {host || "unknown host"}!</p>;

export default Page;
```

But with static generation (`getStaticProps`), the hostname is not available, because there is no request to get it from. In general, a server doesn't know its own public hostname, so you need to tell it. Using [Next.js environment variables](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables), put this in `.env.local`:

```
HOST=example.com
```

Then access it with `process.env['HOST']`:

```
import type { GetStaticProps } from "next";

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = 
  async context => ({ props: { host: process.env['HOST'] || null }});
```

Comment: I had to use this approach of `getStaticProps` when using SSG w/ ISR (revalidate), otherwise the env property wasn't available directly in my page route. I was able to read the env property successfully from the next.js app service app settings instead of the .env.production file.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to get the full URL:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

```
const { asPath } = useRouter();
    const origin =
        typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.origin
            ? window.location.origin
            : '';

    const URL = `${origin}${asPath}`;
    console.log(URL);
```

Comment: that does not return the host name

Comment: @ekkis  `origin` gives you the hostname and `asPath` gives you the rest of the path.

Comment: there is no host name for static-side rendering.  there cannot be, because there isn't a request available

Comment: in Next.js It will have Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
   "next": "12.1.6", 
    "react": "18.1.0",

Comment: @AndyHo, does that happen even when the check for window has been done?

Comment: This is not a good solution. It doesn't support SSR and will generate hydration errors

Comment: `window` is sadly never a good solution in the React world. It only generates hydration errors and problems on the longer run, due to how it works. I'd advise against this and use the answer of @jameshfisher. You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app) for more examples of `window` being a problem.

Answer (score 16):

The place where you are accessing the `window` make sure you add a check so that code is executed only on the browser and no during SSG"

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
   const hostname = window.location.hostname;
}
```

**Update**:
If you have specified `basePath` in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: 'https://www.example.com/docs',
}
```

Then using `useRouter`, you can access the base path:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

function Component() {
   const router = useRouter();
   
   console.log({ basePath: router.basePath}); 
   // { basePath: 'https://www.example.com/docs' }

   ...
}
```

But if you have a relative base path then you can use the first approach

Comment: The `basePath` part does not work as it is just used for shortening the path. You can't use an url there.

Comment: doesn't work with `basePath` in latest nextjs

Answer (score 14):

According to the [answer mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76056858/6908282), you can use below code to get hostname in Next 13 using the new app directory (for server side components):

```js
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default function Home() {
  const headersList = headers();
  
  headersList.get('host'); // to get domain
  headersList.get('next-url'); // to get url

  return <div>....</div>
}
```

> NOTE: please note that [Using it in a layout or page will opt a route into dynamic rendering at request time](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers#:%7E:text=Using%20it%20in%20a%20layout%20or%20page%20will%20opt%20a%20route%20into%20dynamic%20rendering%20at%20request%20time)

Comment: This is the way to go with react 13!

Comment: It works on NextJs 13 and 14. Thanks.

Comment: headersList.get('next-url') returns null

Answer (score 11):

Consider this package > [next-absolute-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-absolute-url)

```
import absoluteUrl from 'next-absolute-url'
const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req)
const apiURL = `${origin}/api/job.js`
```

If you deployed your Next.js app with now the apiURL will be something like `https://your-app.now.sh/api/job.js`.

However, if you are running the app locally the apiURL will be `http://localhost:8000/api/job.js` instead.

Comment: I think its for server-side requests in getInitialProps, but this is the answer that i looking for. thanks anyway

Comment: @Necrofantaisie It looks like `next-absolute-url` also supports client side https://github.com/jakeburden/next-absolute-url/blob/master/index.js#L13

Comment: req is undefined

Comment: Installing an unmaintained external dependency for such a small thing is not recommended, especially in enterprise production apps. Easy solutions directly implemented in your codebase is better than installing a package for this and that.

Answer (score 8):

Using `typeof window !== 'undefined'` is the secure way. `if (window) {}` will run you into problems.

```
const hostname = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.hostname ? window.location.hostname : '';
const origin = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.origin ? window.location.origin : '';
```

Using above code will give you the frontend/outside hostname/origin the client using: `example.com`, `www.example.com`, `www.example.com:80` and so on, not the `localhost` stuff. `useRouter()` will return the server side hostname/origin (`localhost`, `localhost:3000`)

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're better of doing this with a combination of `useRouter` and `useEffect` hooks. In my case I wanted to dynamically set the `og:url` of my webpage. This is what I did. We have `router.pathname` as a dependency so that `ogUrl` is updated every time we move to a different page.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  const [ogUrl, setOgUrl] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    const host = window.location.host;
    const baseUrl = `https://${host}`;

    setOgUrl(`${baseUrl}${router.pathname}`);
  }, [router.pathname]);


  return <div></div>
}
```

Comment: but og: is done either on server side or render at fisrt page loaded

your implmentation would not work if you disabled the javascript

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure your access to `window.location.hostname` happens on the client-side only, and not during server-side rendering (where `window` does not exist). You can achieve that by moving it to a `useEffect` callback in your component.

```js
function Component() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(window.location.hostname) 
        console.log(window.location.href) // Logs `http://localhost:3000/blog/incididunt-ut-lobare-et-dolore`
    }, [])
    
    // Remaining code of the component
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved it, and this also works with Next.js 13 App Router:

Create a hook, call it use-origin.jsx (or .tsx), and add it to the /hooks folder in the root:

```
'use client'; // this is Next 13 App Router stuff

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useOrigin() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const origin = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.origin ? window.location.origin : '';

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true)
  }, [])

  if (!mounted) {
    return null
  }

  return origin;
}
```

Now use this hook to access your dynamic BASE_URL route:

```
"use client";

import useOrigin from "@/hooks/use-origin"

export default function Test() {
  const origin = useOrigin();

  return (
    <div>{origin}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

req.headers are Symbols and not Objects, so to get value, you use the get method

```
const host = req.headers.get("host"); // stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: and how do I get the `req` object in a NextJs page?

Comment: that's actually for middleware in next.js and API pages

Answer (score 1):

none oh the answers above solved the problem and this is the solution i figured it out :

```
function return_url(context) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    // if you are hosting a http website use http instead of https
    return `https://${context.req.rawHeaders[1]}`;
  } else if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
    return "http://localhost:3000";
  }
}
```

and on the getServerSideProps or getStaticProps functions you use

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  let url = return_url(context);
  const data = await fetch(`${url}/yourEndPoint`).then((res) => res.json());
  return {
    props: {
      data: data,
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a **middleware.js** file that you add to the root of your project can give you access to the host name and provide a lot of flexibility to perform actions based on it if needed.

https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

```
// Example: redirecting a domain to a subdomain

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request) {
  // Currently there is no main site so we redirect to the subdomain.
  const host = request.headers.get("Host");
  if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" &&
    host.startsWith("mydomain.com")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("https://mysubdomain.mydomain.com"));
  } else if (
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "staging" &&
    host.startsWith("staging.mydomain.com")
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL("https://mysubdomain-staging.mydomain.com")
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a nice easy way to do this in app dir.

```js
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default function Page() {
  const headerList = headers();
  const domain = headerList.get("x-forwarded-host") || headerList.get("host") || "beta.popstarz.ai";
  console.log(domain);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between py-3 pb-safe-bottom">
       ... 
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: It is for Server Component, is there any way to use in Client Component

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are two ways of doing this:

1. Next JS provides us with the [useRouter hook](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router), first you have to import it in your component, then, to use the router object, you just have to declare it. For example:

   const router = useRouter();

   console.log(router.pathname);

   const {pathname} = router; <---- To access the pathname directly.

Besides this, as @Xairoo said before, if you want to use the window object, you have to check if `window !== 'undefined'` to avoid errors. The *window not defined* error happens because Next JS use NodeJS to render the app and the window object is not defined in Node JS.

You can find a more detailed explanation in [this](https://frontend-digest.com/why-is-window-not-defined-in-nextjs-44daf7b4604e) link.

Answer (score 0):

You just need -> `window.location.href`

[image]

Answer (score -3):

We can get current url like this:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const router = useRouter();
const origin = typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.location.origin ? window.location.origin : '';

const address_url = origin+router.asPath;
```