# How to get origin or domain name in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, url, next.js, server-side-rendering

I can get the relative pathname using `useRouter().asPath` which gives something like `/my-awesome-post` but how to get the origin?
Similar to what `window.location.origin` gives like `https://www.google.com`.

[Next.js Router docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) doesn't mention anything about how to get origin.

I can't use `window.location.origin` (next.js gives an error that window is not defined) so what is my alternative?
I want to get the origin inside a component which is not calling `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: You can access `window` from within a `useEffect` hook.

Comment: I want to avoid using useEffect just for this purpose

Comment: So I can better understand the problem you're having, is there some technical reason why you want to avoid this?

Comment: there's no technical barrier as such but wouldn't using hook add to the performance cost. Since it's just a static value I was hoping for some simple solution.

Comment: the answers posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65199051/6908282) are better.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are on client-side:

  ```
  window.location.origin
  ```
- if you are on the server

  That means you are either in serverside functions or api functions. In both cases you have access to `req` object. In node.js we could get the origin

  ```
  req.get('host')
  ```

But in next.js we do not have `get` property on `req`. so I use this npm package: [next-absolute-url](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-absolute-url)

```
import absoluteUrl from 'next-absolute-url'

const { origin } = absoluteUrl(req);
```

Comment: The first don't work on client side. I'm getting undefined for window

Comment: If you are on next 13 client, you still have to check if (typeof window!==“undefined”) because client components gets rendered on the server first