# Getting the Site URL in Next.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js, next-router

I am setting up a Next.JS site and would like to retrieve the site url.  For example, if I have a local install, then the site url would be `localhost:3000`.  If I deploy the site, then it would be `www.my-domainame.com`.

I thought I could do this via the next.js `useRouter` hook.  But upon closer look it does not seem to return that information.  It has information about the path and query, but not about the site url.

As such, I am wondering -- how can I do this in Next.JS?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to get page URL or hostname in NextJs Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199051/how-to-get-page-url-or-hostname-in-nextjs-project)?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-absolute-url