# What is the most optimal way to serve content based on user geolocation (in next,js app router)

Tags: geolocation, subdomain, url-routing, middleware, next.js13

### Objective

- We have a webapp made in next.js (app router) under a specific domain **([www.exampleDomain.in](http://www.exampleDomain.in))**
- We want to set up a subdomain **([www.exampleDomain.com.au](http://www.exampleDomain.com.au))** that **serves the same content but with some changes**
- eg. different portfolio page, teams page for different users based on geolocation

---

### Approach / Concept

We're currently exploring two approaches:

1. Clone the repository, change the desired content, setup a subdomain and serve for different domains
2. Keep the same repository, create desired content and conditionally render based on geolocation. (achieve this using middleware provided by next.js)

---

### Attempts

We have been trying to understand more about middleware

a. Define a middleware, match and redirect (from domain to subdomain)
[conditional rendering using middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#conditional-statements)
[middleware: content based on geolocation](https://youtu.be/NUHAc1wjL3A?si=TwLbSeqSDuXfiOjs)

b. Use "window.location.origin", and conditionally render the component (works only on client)

```
about/
└── about.js
└── about-au.js
└── ...
```

[How to get page URL or hostname in NextJs Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199051/how-to-get-page-url-or-hostname-in-nextjs-project)

c. use next/headers data to get the domain and conditionally render
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345990

---

### The question

I want to understand which one of the two approaches mentioned is better and what is the conventional way of achieving this objective?