# NextJS styled-components giving an error in bundle file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I am using [styled-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components) for my React project. After I bundled my react application with rollupjs then  I am trying to use this bundle with NextJS. It is getting error in NextJS:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

When I look line of error in the bundle file this error is happening inside of styled-components.

Here is my `rollup.config.js` in React App (not Nextjs):

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import external from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import image from "@rollup/plugin-image";
import visualizer from "rollup-plugin-visualizer";
import pkg from "./package.json";

// PostCSS plugins
import simplevars from "postcss-simple-vars";
import nested from "postcss-nested";
import cssnext from "postcss-cssnext";
import cssnano from "cssnano";
import cssvariables from "postcss-css-variables";

const extensions = [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"];

export default {
  input: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: "cjs",
      globals: { react: "React" },
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: "esm",
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(["react", "uikit"]),
    postcss({
      plugins: [
        simplevars(),
        cssvariables(),
        nested(),
        cssnext({ warnForDuplicates: false }),
        cssnano(),
      ],
      extensions: [".css"],
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: "node_modules/**",
      extensions,
    }),
    // Allows node_modules resolution
    resolve({
      mainFields: ["module", "main", "jsnext:main", "browser"],
      dedupe: ["react", "react-dom"], // Default: []
      extensions,
    }),
    commonjs(),
    image(),
    visualizer(),
  ],
};
```

How can I solve this error in NextJS with bundle code?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "After I bundled my react application with rollupjs then I am trying to use this bundle with NextJS"? Are you trying to use a library you own on another Next.js project?

Comment: Yes it is correct. I use react bundle for NextJS app in node_modules as a nodejs package.

Comment: Without having access to your React library it's difficult to say what's causing the issue exactly. However, it does sound like you're trying to use the library on the server-side somehow, where `window` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

It means your `window` related code is executed on the Node.js side, not on the browser. Since Next.js is server-side rendering framework, you should make sure that you don't use browser thing (like `window` object) in the code that is executed on the server side.
Please reference [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app).

**UPDATE**

Please check your `.babelrc` -

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }]]
}
```

Comment: Thank you I know this but I didn't use window global in my react components. It used in styled-components package.

Comment: It is in styled-components node package.You can try to use after bundle. It is not in my react components. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components). It is relevant with this npm package.

Comment: @tcetin Could you check my updated answer?

Comment: I  use styled-components package as "devDependency".I will try but can you explain your answer why it needs like this?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. It gives same error still

Comment: I think you are mentioning same idea with this article: https://medium.com/swlh/server-side-rendering-styled-components-with-nextjs-1db1353e915e. But I don't use styled-components in  nextjs app. I use styled components in normal react application. So these are different react applications.