# Is there any alternative for avoiding this error of localStorage is not defined on server side next js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(async (ctx) => {
    const access_token = cookies(ctx).access_token;
    await ctx.store.dispatch(getData(access_token));
    if (localStorage){
        localStorage.setItem("token", "1234");
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("token"));
    }

});
```

> localStorage is not defined on this line
> `if (localStorage){}`

Comment: localStorage is actually window.localStorage. window will be always undefined on server side.  You can use `if( process.browser ) { ... }` to execute code only on client side. Read more here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare it somewhere, like in the top of the js file, specifying it is global:

```
/* global localStorage, */
```

or, alternatively, use the version tied to window (it is your global object)

```
window.localStorage.setItem("token", "1234");
```

Comment: window is also not defined on server side, and also tried using global localstorage didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Store your token as Cookie instead of LocalStorage.

document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 30 Jan 2021 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";

and access inside getInitialProps or Server Side Methods from "req.headers.cookie"

Comment: yes currently I am using cookies. Just wondered if there is any way of using local or session storage