# How to track value of undefined variable in dependency list in useEffect in React and Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I have a next problem:

I want to track some of field of undefined variable **window**, but which will be defined in future.

For example, if the inner field of variable **window** will be changed, I want to do some code.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window && window.innerWidth) {
        // Do something
    }
}, [window.innerWidth])
```

But next.js and react writes following:

[image]

How to achieve this effect? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Maybe this could help => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151041/window-is-not-defined-in-next-js-react-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will work for your use case.

So we have 2 `useEffect` hooks.

The first `useEffect` attached an event listener to the `window` object. Because the `window` is used in a `useEffect` hook, it won't be executed on the server-side.

The second `useEffect` hook will listen to the state changes on `innerWidth`, which is being updated whenever the `resize` event happens.

```js
  const [innerWidth, setInnerWidth] = useState<number | undefined>();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handler to call on window resize
    function handleResize() {
      setInnerWidth(window.innerWidth);
    }

    // Add event listener
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
    handleResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []); 

  useEffect(() => {
    // Handle your changes
    console.log(innerWidth);
  }, [innerWidth]);
```

Inspired by this [useWindowResize implementation](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using process.browser to just execute your command during rendering on the client side only.

```
   if (typeof window !== "undefined") { //client side code } 

/*OR TRY THIS */
/*Remove dependency array*/
useEffect(() => {
    if (window && window.innerWidth) {
        // Do something
    }
}, [])
```