# Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined when I import a client-side library?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, xtermjs

Trying to create an [xterm](https://xtermjs.org/) react component in **Next.js** I got stuck as I'm not able to get over an error message I've never got before.

I'm trying to import a npm client-side module called `xterm`, but if I add the import line the application crashes.

```js
import { Terminal } from 'xterm'
```

The error reads `Server Error... ReferenceError: self is not defined`
and then shows this chunk of code as `Source`

```js
module.exports = require("xterm");
```

According to some research I did, this has to do with Webpack and could be helped if something like this was done:

```js
output: {
  globalObject: 'this'
}
```

Would you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The error occurs because the library requires Web APIs to work, which are not available when [Next.js pre-renders the page](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering) on the server-side.

In your case, `xterm` tries to access the `window` object which is not present on the server. The solution is to avoid loading `xterm` on the server and dynamically import it so it gets loaded on the client-side only.

There are a couple of ways to achieve this in Next.js.

---

#### #1 Using dynamic `import()` inside `useEffect`

Move the `import` to your component's `useEffect`, then dynamically import the library and add your logic there.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const initTerminal = async () => {
        const { Terminal } = await import('xterm')
        const term = new Terminal()
        // Add logic with `term`
    }
    initTerminal()
}, [])
```

---

#### #2 Using `next/dynamic` with `ssr: false`

Create a component where you add the `xterm` logic.

```js
// components/terminal-component
import { Terminal } from 'xterm'

function TerminalComponent() {
    const term = new Terminal()
    // Add logic around `term`
    return <></>
}

export default TerminalComponent
```

Then dynamically import that component when using it.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const TerminalComponent = dynamic(() => import('<path-to>/components/terminal-component'), {
    ssr: false
})
```

As an *alternative*, you could add the logic directly when dynamically importing the library with `next/dynamic` to avoid having an extra file for it.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const Terminal = dynamic(
    {
        loader: () => import('xterm').then((mod) => mod.Terminal),
        render: (props, Terminal) => {
            const term = new Terminal()
            // Add logic with `term`
            return <></>
        }
    },
    {
        ssr: false
    }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried this but it doesn't seem to be importing the `{ Terminal }` constructor. What I get instead is an `someobject = {}` with a `$$typeof:` and `render:` properties. Would you know why this would be?

Comment: I've solved it by doing an `import { Terminal } from 'xterm'` in my component and then importing that `<Component />` with the `dynamic()` function in the parent page. I could mark your answer as correct if you mention this detail.

Comment: Ah right, I assumed `Terminal` was a component - Next.js `dynamic` must return a component. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You have no idea how your answer saved me.. thanks...

Comment: Are you able to explain why is not `'use client'` fixing this kind of issue in next.js v13? I still had to opt for these dynamic imports

Comment: @crollywood Using `use client` does not make the component only render on the client-side. It simply means the component will _also_ get rendered on the client in addition to the server-side rendering. As opposed to Server Components (components that do not use `use client`), where the rendering only occurs on the server.

Comment: @juliomalves OK that makes perfect sense. Thanks! I was about to say that `use client` was badly explained in [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components), but after rereading I can see that it actually is explained in `How are Client Components Rendered?` section.

Comment: I've crafted a complete answer in another slightly related question to handle other situation where the library can be imported server-side, but can't be used there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77556387/5513532

Comment: Need to replace `self` with `globalThis`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77843487/3414249

Answer (score 0):

Need to replace `self` with `globalThis`, see

- https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/3764#issuecomment-1870984332
- https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/commit/de1304d19e8436427cfa7cb660861f373cd32a18
- https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/pull/4940

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the default export and found it helpful to add the import with the `default` property like so:

```js
const [doStuff, setDoStuff] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
 const exportFileAsPDF = async () => {
        const {default: html2pdf} = await import('html2pdf.js');

        if (typeof window === "undefined") return
        if (typeof document === "undefined") return

        if (content && html2pdf) {
           // use library
           HTML_CONTENT = ""
           pdfOptions = {}
           html2pdf().from(HTML_CONTENT).set(pdfOptions).save();
           setDoStuff(false)
          }
      }

    if (doStuff){
        exportFileAsPDF()
    }
}, [doStuff])
```