# Import PeerJs to NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, peerjs

So I'm learning NextJs and trying to build a audio chat app and I'm stuck when I try to import `PeerJs`

Its throwing an window is not defined error.

```
import Peer from 'peerjs';

export default function Home() {

useEffect(() => {
  const myPeer = new Peer(undefined, {
    host: '/',
    port: '3001'
  })
}, [])
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780? It references `xterm`, but the same would apply to `peerjs`.

Comment: @juliomalves thank you very much I got it working now..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because using nextjs, code is first evaluated in server side (render to HTML). At this stage, `window`is not defined. This is probably because peer js is performing some side effect during import. To workaround this, you could use dynamic import:

```
useEffect(() => {
  import('peerjs').then(({ default: Peer }) => {
    // Do your stuff here
  });
}, [])
```

Comment: How can I import `DataConnection` also, I have TypeScript. need here: `peer.on('connection', (conn: DataConnection) => {` I need replace this: `import Peer, { DataConnection } from 'peerjs'`.

Comment: looks like you just need the type, put this in the top: `import { type  DataConnection  } from 'peerjs';` You will import DataConnection as type only then and tsc will simply remove it when compiling.