# How to use Peer.js in Next.js with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, peerjs

Next.js runs on server side also, so Peer.js raise error when using Next.js. Here one says: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66292100/239219

> this is probably because peer js is performing some side effect during import.

He propose this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  import('peerjs').then(({ default: Peer }) => {
    // Do your stuff here
  });
}, [])
```

But I need `DataConnection` as using Typescript, and also asign it to a useState. would you show an example how?

This is what I put togeter, but TypesScript raise errors:

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        import('peerjs').then(({ default: Peer, DataConnection }) => {
            const peer = new Peer(localStorage.token)

            peer.on('connection', (conn: DataConnection) => {
                console.log('Connected to peer:', conn)

                conn.on('data', (data) => {
                    console.log('Received data:', data)
                })
            })

            return () => {
                peer.destroy()
            }
        })
    }, [])
```

like: 'DataConnection' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof DataConnection'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [type-only import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export) (introduced in version 3.8) at the top of the file:

```
import type { DataConnection } from "peerjs";
```

This import will be erased in the output, so rest assured that this will not import it "early".

---

Or if that doesn't fancy you, you can also "inline" the import:

```
peer.on('connection', (conn: import("peerjs").DataConnection) => {
```

Looks weird, but when `import(...)` is used as a type, it resolves to the namespace that importing the module would give you.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the component that is using peerjs (and its other imports) on the client.

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

let WebRTC = dynamic(() => import("./main"), { ssr: false, loading: () => 
    <h2>loading..</h2> })

export default function Page() {

    return (
       <WebRTC />
    )

}
```

By setting *ssr: false* you tell next to load it only on the client side.
Check for more info *https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/lazy-loading#nextdynamic*