# Import npm when document is ready (ReactJS/Next.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, next.js

I'm trying to use this small js library called float-sidebar.js, I've installed the module via npm, but I noticed in react it throws error "window" not defined, because "window" is used inside the code float-sidebar.min.js inside the module without checking if window loaded or ready.

Since I'm using Next.js I've tried to dynamically load the module like:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const FloatSidebar = dynamic(
  () => import('float-sidebar'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

doing so it doesn't throw the "window" undefined error anymore, but it says `FloatSidebar` is not a function later on in my code:

```
const handleScroll = () => {

    const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
    const relative = document.querySelector('.content');

    const floatSidebar = FloatSidebar({
      sidebar: sidebar,
      relative: relative,
      topSpacing: 40,
      bottomSpacing: 40
    });

    floatSidebar.forceUpdate();
  }
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question: [Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined in Next.js when I try to import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780)?

Comment: @juliomalves almost, I also thought of the component trick the problem is what i'm importing isn't a component rather a function, exported from that module .js file

Comment: That's also the case in the question I linked.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the regular [ES2020 dynamic import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) on `float-sidebar` inside your `handleScroll` callback.

```js
const handleScroll = () => {
    const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
    const relative = document.querySelector('.content');
    
    const FloatSidebar = (await import('float-sidebar')).default;
    const floatSidebar = FloatSidebar({
      sidebar: sidebar,
      relative: relative,
      topSpacing: 40,
      bottomSpacing: 40
    });
    floatSidebar.forceUpdate();
}
```