# How to use Firebase cloud messaging in nextJs

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js

I have tried to use Firebase cloud messaging with next.js

```
Server Error
ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

I am having above error while running my next.js app

This is my code

```
import 'firebase/messaging';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
const firebaseConfig = {
//passed correct data
}
export const auth = firebase.auth();
export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const storage = firebase.storage();
export const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096260/webpack-why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined-in-next-js-when-i