# New module import error => "ReferenceError: self is not defined"

Tags: reactjs, encryption, next.js, local-storage

```
import { EncryptStorage } from 'encrypt-storage';

export const encryptStorage = EncryptStorage('secret_key');

encryptStorage.setItem('user', userObj);
```

error :

[image]

I am trying to encrypt the localstorage using **encrypt-storage** but the import is giving me error and project crashed after putting only 3 line of code.

Dynamic import of next is not working as most of the solution i found is for component not for package.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66096260/webpack-why-am-i-getting-referenceerror-self-is-not-defined-in-next-js-when-i) is not working for dynamic module import as i am getting some assignment error in loader.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question: [(Webpack) Why am I getting ReferenceError: self is not defined in Next.js when I try to import a client-side library?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780)? Essentially, you should only import `encrypt-storage` on the client.

Comment: Not working, i tried. still if you can make small example in code sandbox then its more clear for me @juliomalves