# Using azure-maps-control package with Next.js

Tags: next.js, azure-maps

Is anyone using this package successfully with Next.js?

I'm importing the package as is written in the docs `import * as atlas from 'azure-maps-control'`.

If I try to use anything from `atlas` I get the same
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00ftl.png)

You can replicate the issue by setting up a fresh Next.js app, adding this package and trying to use it.

Importing atlas as CDN works but I need to use azure-maps-control.

Comment: Looks like `azure-maps-control` depends on the DOM being present to work, so you'll probably need to [import it on the client-side only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100185/1870780).

Comment: @shota did you have any luck with the suggestion above?

Comment: @asergaz Yes. I dynamically imported the component with `ssr: false` which was using azure-maps-control. It worked.

Comment: Go ahead and post the answer + verify for others benefit!